# Firestore whereEqualTo, orderBy and limit(1) not working

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to query my Workout Collection for the latest workout from a routine.  Meaning I query with `whereEqualTo` my routineKey, order it by the Started TimeStamp in descending order and then limit to 1 and then take the this 1st Key/Id of the Workout.

However this does not work. `whereEqualTo` and `orderBy` work separately but not combined. What am I doing wrong?

```
fm.getColRefWorkout().whereEqualTo("routineKey", routineKey).orderBy("startTimeStamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(1).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() { 
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots) {
                    workoutKey = documentSnapshots.getDocuments().get(0).getId();
                    //To stuff with this workoutKey
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This query will not work unless you create an [index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing) for it. This can be done, by creating it manually in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/) or if you are using Android Studio, you'll find in your logcat a message that sounds like this:

```
FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index. You can create it here: ...
```

You can simply click on that link or copy and paste the URL into a web browser and your index will be created automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Haven't got a LogCat message but I created an index manually it worked.

Comment: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('messages')
                .where('encSenderUId', isEqualTo: _loggedInUserId)
                .orderBy('sentOn', descending: false)
                .snapshots(), I want to do orderBy by `SentOn` field, not by encSenderUId then why firebase console says to encSenderUId to index by providing link. Its weird. Kindly suggest. Thanks.

Comment: @Kamlesh Without seeing the entire code, I can't be much of a help. So please post a new question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: I have created index for the same and it worked. It was odd but I did to solve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: I broke my head over this issue -  documentation says where and orderBy can't be used on different fields, whereas the answers above suggest that compound index creation would suffice. I am trying to do this and it doesn't work collection('users').where('uid', isNotEqualTo: user.uid).orderBy('accountCreationDate', descending: false)

Comment: @bekon Without seeing your index, it is hard to tell why it isn't working the way you expect. So please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: thanks, just posted my question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71938862/combining-where-and-orderby-clauses-in-firestore-flutter