# How to implement multiple order by in android firestore based on different if conditions?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How to implement multiple order by in Android `Firestore` based on different if conditions?

I want to sort my firestore items based on different fieldvalues 
like this:

```
Query query= firestoredb.collection('items').document(docid).orderby('price').orderby('itemcategory').orderby('name**');
```

But how many `orderby` will be added is **dynamic** . It will decide during runtime i.e what user will select from sort options.

So how would I make my `Firestore` query in android?

Please help me.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```
 Query query=firestoredb.collection("items"); 
 if(PRICE.equals("price")) {
      query = query.orderby('price'); 
 }
 if(NAME.equals("name")) {
      query = query.orderby('name'); 
 }
 if("itemCategory"){
      query = query.orderby('itemCategory');
 }
```

Comment: This solution is the same solution as mine but only that you have used an `if statement` rather then a `switch statement`. The main difference is that your code doesn't solve the situaton in which you need to order by two properties, as you original request was.

Comment: Hi @Alex,
You are adding an **orderby** in firebase collection and assigning it to **query** object and in each case statement you are replacing the  **query** object. Also you are using multiple **orderby** to make a combination i.e for two properties(name,item) there must be 4 possible case statement required 
 similarly for 3 properties(name,item,category) 6 possible case statements will be needed and here In my code I am appending the **orderby** with the previous **query** object and yes my code solve the situation in which I need to order by two properties, as my original request was.

Comment: So if you say that your original question was to order by two properties and my answer solves your problem, why to accept an answer which contains not even half of a solution? This may confuse future visitors.

Answer (score 4):

A query like the one you are using in your code:

```
Query query= firestoredb.collection('items').document(docid).orderby('price').orderby('itemcategory').orderby('name');
```

Is not possible in Cloud Firestore because `firestoredb.collection('items').document(docid)` return a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference) object and you cannot call `orderBy()` method on it. So assuming you want to use a query, the following line of code:

```
Query query= firestoredb.collection('items').orderby('price').orderby('itemcategory').orderby('name');
```

Will work perfectly fine. There is no problem in Firestore to order by multiple fields. You can even set the direction passing as the second argument: `Direction.ASCENDING` or `Direction.DESCENDING`.

**Edit:**

According to your comment, you should create an if statement or even better, a switch statement and accordingly to what the user is seleting to create a **new** query object. So if the user selects only price, then the query should look like this: `firestoredb.collection('items').orderby('price')`, that's it. See an example below:

```
Query query;
switch (option) {
    case "price":
        query = firestoredb.collection('items').orderby('price');
        break;
    case "itemcategory":
        query = firestoredb.collection('items').orderby('itemcategory');
        break;
    case "price_itemcategory":
        query = firestoredb.collection('items').orderby('price').orderby('itemcategory');
        break;
    case "name":
        query = firestoredb.collection('items').orderby('name');
        break;
    case "price_name":
        query = firestoredb.collection('items').orderby('price').orderby('name');
        break;
    default:
        query = firestoredb.collection('items'); //No ordering
        break;
```

Comment: Yes , I agree with you that there is no problem in Firestore to order by multiple fields but my question is how I dynamically add or remove my orderby fields based on user input  i.e what user will select from order by options?

It could be  orderby('price') only 
It could be orderby('itemcategory') and orderby('price') 
or It could be orderby('name') and orderby('price')

Comment: In this case, please see my updated answer. Is this ok now?

Comment: Thank you Its working but making multiple possible combination of  cases making it more typical
instead of it I have found a another way  just like that

Query query=firestoredb.collection('items');
       if('price')  
        query = query.orderby('price');
      if('name')  
        query = query.orderby('name');
 if('itemCategory')
  query = query.orderby('itemCategory');

Comment: Which is tipically the same thing :) But good to hear that it worked.

Comment: I did same but it raises error of "Error: 9 FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index." help

Comment: how do I create indexing programatically. After exploring about it, it is said that when you need to do dynamic indexing then your model structure is bad. But for above code how to deal with indexing???

Comment: @Onk_r You need to create an [index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305328/firestore-whereequalto-orderby-and-limit1-not-working) for each case in order to make it work.