# firebase query at same values

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a query:

```
const q = query(collection(db, 'users'), orderBy("highScore", "desc"));
```

Which returns all the users with all their highscores in descending order.
The problem is that there are users who got the same high scores, and now they are ordered I think randomly. So for example, if 3 users get 3000 score it just randomly orders those 3.
How can I for example look at another field(a timestamp) and order the last to achieve the 3000 pointsfirst and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use orderBy again in order to sort them, try checking this:

```
const q = query(collection(db, 'users'), orderBy("highScore", "desc"), orderBy("timestamp", "desc"));
```

Or, you can do it client-side by sorting them.

You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51983639/how-to-implement-multiple-order-by-in-android-firestore-based-on-different-if-co).