# Get last created document in a Firebase Firestore collection

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any way to get last created document in Firebase Firestore collection? My requirement is when user signed I have to add a document in a collection named 'history'; When the user signed out I want to update that document with a field called 'signout'; So if i get the lastly added document it is very easy to update. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Is there any way to get the last created document in Firebase Firestore collection?

Yes, there is! The simplest way to achieve this is to add a `date` property to each object in your collection, then simply query it according to this new property *descending* and call `limit(1)` function. That's it!

As @eyyo mentioned in his comment, here is a concrete example. Assuming that your database schema looks like this:

```
Firestore-root
  |
  --- history (collection)
        |
        --- docId (document)
             |
             --- date: June 24, 2020 at 6:46:25 PM UTC+3
             |
             --- //Other properties
```

This is the required query:

```
this.historyRef = afs.collection<History>('history', ref => ref.orderBy('date', 'desc').limit(1));
this.history = this.historyRef.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
    return actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Hisotory;
        const docId = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { docId, ...data };
    });
});
```

Comment: can you please explain it.?

Comment: Give it a try and keep me posted.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that you manually have to create a Index for every document it in the Firebase console. 

Is there any other way to get the latest document inserted ?

Comment: @BluE_MoOn Simply adding a `Date` property does **not** require an index. The index is automatically created for you. If you need to query and order, yes, there [an index is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305328/firestore-whereequalto-orderby-and-limit1-not-working).

Comment: Is the `Date` property a field in the collection? Can it exist within a map?

Comment: @Max The `Date` property cannot exist in a collection, only in a document. And yes, the `Date can be added to a Map.

Comment: An example would be very useful!

Comment: Thank you @AlexMamo!

Comment: Thanks for this, I was looking for something similiar. One question though. Doing ref.orderBy('date', 'desc').limit(1) will be ONE READ or Fireabase will consider you've read the whole collection? @AlexMamo

Comment: @1x2x3x4x Yes, it will be indeed **only** one read, as your query only one document returns.