# Cloud Firestore : Fetch document from collection to get last message

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

I am implementing chat using cloud firestore.

I have ChatRoom(collection)-> Messages(collection)

Can anyone help me to fetch last message(Last message sent/received any user from two user in a chatroom) from the Messages collection and show in ChatRoom with last message.

Here i have two collection one inside another, so two asynchronous query will be required for multiple chat room

Comment: How exactly do you define what the last message is?

Comment: Last message sent/received any user from two user in a chatroom

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get last created document in a Firebase Firestore collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54178951/get-last-created-document-in-a-firebase-firestore-collection)

Comment: Here i have two collection one inside another, so two asynchronous query will be required for multiple chat room

Comment: Sounds like you need to store a timestamp field with each message so you can query for the last one.

Comment: I have timestamp field, isDeletedOne, isDeletedTwo, Senderid.  Here when i fetch list of chat room, i also want to fetch last message of each chatroom.