# display information by order ionic firebase

Tags: angular, ionic4

I'm building a blog application with ionic4 and angular. I manage to display the various data of my firebase database, but I would like to display by order of recent information and not old. the one that has just been published must be at the top when displayed and not at the bottom. thank you

Comment: You may find solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54178951/get-last-created-document-in-a-firebase-firestore-collection). Happy Coding :D!

Comment: thanks but that doesn't really help me i show you my code     this.afDB.list('publication/').snapshotChanges(['child_added','child_changed','child_moved','child_removed']).subscribe(actions =>{