# How to get specific collection in Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]
How I can get all collection with `level==2` and `status==on`, order by count?
And limit only the first collection that I can get.  And how can i get the collection value? I need to get the collection and store it since I need it for other function.

I already read Firestore documentation a few times now, but I still cant find the way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How i can get all collection with level==2 and status=="on", order by count?

You cannot get all collections, you can get all documents with that constraint within that collection. The query that you are looking for is:

```
db.collection("User").whereEqualTo("level", 2).whereEqualTo("status", true).limit(1);
```

But rememeber, everytime you are using such a query, an index is required. For that, please see my answer from the following post:

- [Firestore whereEqualTo, orderBy and limit(1) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305328/firestore-whereequalto-orderby-and-limit1-not-working)