# Android Firestore subcollections into RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I am currently working on a Rental Car app in Java Android Studio. For the project database, I am using Cloud Firestore. My database is structured like so:

[image: collection]

Subcollection:
[image: subcollection]

The first image is represented by the collection of Cars with multiple documents with random ID (each represents a car). Every car has a unique subcollection called bookings where are saved in random ID documents details about bookings made to that specific car (the second image is represented by an example of a booking subcollection).

I am currently working at a "Booking history" section. There, I want to put the current user's booking history (highlighted with red in the second image) in a RecyclerView. I know how to iterate between all cars and their subcollection and put and if(bookedBy == currentUser) condition to obtain only the cars booked by the current user.

But my question is: How can I save those in a RecyclerView? I want to save data highlighted in red (second image) in the RecyclerView if our previous condition is met. I don't know what query to put in the Firestore adapter. I was thinking about saving all the cars booked by the user and their dates in an object or something like this but I can't figure it out. Can anyone help me, please?

Thank you!

Comment: Instead of describing how your database looks like, please edit your question and add a screenshot of it. Besides that, please also highlight the exact data you want to get.

Comment: done, added pictures and more explains

Comment: *I know how to iterate between all cars and their subcollection and put and if(bookedBy == currentUser) condition to obtain only the cars booked by the current user*. How did you do that? So if you achieved that, which in my opinion is the key to solving your problem, what exact query are you looking for?

Comment: I don't know how to save all the results in a RecyclerView because as far as I know, you can only pass a query to the FirestoreRecyclerAdapter. How can I achieve this if for example there are 3 cars rented by a user?

Comment: I think I get you. I'll write you an answer right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your database structure, which looks like this:

```
Firestore-root
  |
  --- Cars (collection)
       |
       --- $cardId (document)
             |
             --- bookings (collection)
                  |
                  --- $bookingId
                        |
                        --- bookedBy: "bogdanmaris11@yahoo.com"
                        |
                        --- endDate: 31 May, 2021...
                        |
                        --- finalPrice: 1998
                        |
                        --- startDate: 30 May, 2021...
```

To get all the bookings that correspond to a specific user, a [Cloud Firestore collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) is required. This query looks like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
Query queryByEmail = rootRef.collectionGroup("bookings").whereEqualTo("bookedBy", "bogdanmaris11@yahoo.com");
queryByEmail.get().addOnCompleteListener(/* ... /*);
```

There are three things to notice. To get the desired results from this query, you might check the email address, as you might have a typo, bogdanmari(u)s11@yahoo.com, where the "u" is missing. Second, it's best to filter the users based on their UIDs and not based on their email addresses, because a user can change the email address at any time, while the UID will always remain the same. And the third one, as I understand, you intend to use the [Firebase-UI library](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android), which is good. In this case, the "queryByEmail" should be passed to FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder's `setQuery()` method. However, there might be an issue, because each query requires an [index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305328/firestore-whereequalto-orderby-and-limit1-not-working), and the [numbers of indexes are limited in Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#indexes).

According to what you wrote:

> I was thinking about saving all the cars booked by the user and their dates in an object or something like this but I can't figure it out.

That's a great idea. That's not about an object, as it more about a sub-collection or a new top-level collection, where you can nest all bookings that correspond to a specific user. In the first case, your schema will look like this:

```
Firestore-root
  |
  --- bookings (collection)
       |
       --- $uid (document) //Not email address
             |
             --- userBookings (collection)
                  |
                  --- $bookingId
                        |
                        --- carId: "YI1J ... VSm0"
                        |
                        --- endDate: 31 May, 2021...
                        |
                        --- finalPrice: 1998
                        |
                        --- startDate: 30 May, 2021...
```

Where there is no need for any email address in the `Booking` object, however a "cardId" is required, if you need the car data. To get all booking of a single user, the following reference is needed:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference userBookingsRef = rootRef.collection("bookings").document(uid).collection("userBookings");
userBookingsRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(/* ... /*);
```

And in the second:

```
Firestore-root
  |
  --- allBookings (collection)
        |
        --- $bookingId
               |
               --- bookedBy: "longUid"
               |
               --- carId: "YI1J ... VSm0"
               |
               --- endDate: 31 May, 2021...
               |
               --- finalPrice: 1998
               |
               --- startDate: 30 May, 2021...
```

Where is a simple query (without index) will do the trick:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
Query QueryByUid = rootRef.collection("allBookings").whereEqualTo("uid", uid);
QueryByUid.get().addOnCompleteListener(/* ... /*);
```

Pass the first reference or this Query to your "FirestoreRecyclerAdapter" and that's pretty much of it.

Comment: Very useful information. Thank you very very much as it helped me solve the problem!