# Multiple QUERY filters on Firebase Collection

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to apply multiple query filters on a Firestore collection but I have no idea how to do it. If I apply one filter, it works fine.

Part of my code:

```
private ArrayList<TaskItem> taskList;
private CollectionReference tasks;

taskList = new ArrayList<>();
tasks = firestore.collection("Tasks");

queryData();

private void queryData(){
        taskList.clear();

        tasks.whereEqualTo("recipient", user.getEmail())
                .whereNotEqualTo("status", "Completed")
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        for(QueryDocumentSnapshot document : queryDocumentSnapshots){
                            TaskItem item = document.toObject(TaskItem.class);
                            taskList.add(item);
                        }

                        if(taskList.size() == 0){
                            initalizeData();
                            queryData();
                        }

                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/q/26700924/9185361
You can put multiple clauses as
tasks.whereEqualTo("recipient", user.getEmail())
                .whereNotEqualTo("status", "Completed")
                .whereEqualTo("someKey", "SomeValue")
                .get()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to filter documents from Firestore using [whereEqualTo()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query#whereEqualTo(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) together with [whereNotEqualTo()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query#whereNotEqualTo(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)), an **index** is required. To create such an index, please see my answer from the following post:

- [Firestore whereEqualTo, orderBy and limit(1) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305328/firestore-whereequalto-orderby-and-limit1-not-working)

Once you create the index, you'll be able to map the documents from Firestore into objects of type "TaskItem" and add them to the adapter.