# How to order by time remaining for gamers if their scores are equal in Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, collections

I am making a game app and I want to list user's scores descending. I could list scores descending in the leaderboard so far, but what if the users scores are equal? Then I want whoever completed the game in less time to go up in that list. I would like to list users like that : [if scores of the user is equal, which user has more time left he will go up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLkHu.png)

Here is my code :

```
   val query: Query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        .collection("Scores")
        .orderBy("score",Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
        .limit(50)

    val options: FirestoreRecyclerOptions<LeaderModel> = FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<LeaderModel>()
        .setQuery(query, LeaderModel::class.java)
        .build()


    adapter = FBRecyclerAdapter(options)
    binding?.recyclerViewLeaderBoard?.adapter = adapter
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but what if the users scores are equal?

If two users have the same score, you should implement a mechanism to differentiate them.

> Then I want whoever completed the game in less time to go up in that list.

To achieve this you should add a new `.orderBy()` call like this:

```
val query: Query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    .collection("Scores")
    .orderBy("score", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
    .orderBy("time", Query.Direction.DESCENDING) //Newly added
    .limit(50)
```

This means that you should add a new property inside each document that exists in the "Scores" collection that can hold the time in which a user has completed the game.

```
Firestore--root
  |
  --- Scores (collection)
       |
       --- $scoreId (document)
             |
             --- score: 100
             |
             --- time: 30 //Time in seconds
```

In order to make it work, don't also forget to create an index, as explained in my answer from the following post:

> [Firestore whereEqualTo, orderBy and limit(1) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305328/firestore-whereequalto-orderby-and-limit1-not-working)

So your index should be on the following fields:

```
score Descending time Descending
```