# Filter RecyclerView by date from datepicker- Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Revisied Qustion:

[Firestore database structure screenshot][2]

Mr.Alex,

#1. Indexing done via Logcat

#2. `date` format is

```
 '2021-08-20 15:25:34.888 30176-30176/com.kasthu.prkeng D/TAG: Date is: Fri Aug 20 05:30:00 GMT+05:30 2021'
```

and my Firestore Timestamp format is

[Firestore Timestamp format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwiXo.png)

Note: `date` is in "GMT" format and Timestamp is in "UTC" format--kindly advise on this
and my simplified code code is -i am using "FirestoreRecyclerAdapter"

```
'FirestoreRecyclerOptions<model> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<model>() 
.setQuery(df.orderBy("FullName", Query.Direction.ASCENDING) 
.whereEqualTo("TimeIn", date), model.class)
.build(); 
adapter = new fsattadapter(options); 
review.setAdapter(adapter);
```

if i include  `whereEqualTo("TimeIn", date)` in query, Recyclerview doesn't show anything.Kindly advise

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: Greetings Mr.Alex, i have attached Database structure .thank you

Comment: What's the value of `date` inside your query? Can you log it?

Comment: 2021-08-19 15:47:43.881 19468-19468/com.kasthu.prkeng D/TAG: Date is15-08-2021

Comment: So the value of `date` inside `.whereEqualTo("TimeIn",date)` is **15-08-2021**, right?

Comment: yes it is correct

Comment: i think we are required to update recycler adapter everytime while the date changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a possibility for the existence of several problems in your code, but I found the two major ones.

The problems is that the following query:

```
 df.orderBy("FullName", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
      .whereEqualTo("TimeIn",date)
```

Requires an [index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305328/firestore-whereequalto-orderby-and-limit1-not-working). Even if you create the corresponding index, the query will not work because you pass to the `.whereEqualTo()` method a `date` which is in String format (15-08-2021), while in the database is a Firestore timestamp. So you cannot use a String when querying the database instead of a Timestamp and expect to behave correctly. To solve this, you should pass instead of a String a [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object and your query will work perfectly fine.

Comment: ok, Thank you so much, i try to rectify it

Comment: Cool. Give it a try and tell me if it works ;)

Comment: Mr.Alex i have tried and simplified my code and i updated my question.kindly have a look

Comment: To be able to get the desired result, the `date` object should contain the exact same value it exists in the database and in the same format. Otherwise, it won't work.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Alex for yor valuable input...✔️ done

Answer (score 0):

i thing your filtering criteria is  not working,

```
df.orderBy("FullName", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
                               .whereEqualTo("TimeIn",edDatePick.getText().toString)
                                .get()                               
                            .addOnSuccessListener(newOnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey Finaly i solved this  filtering by date. But by storing Date as string in firestore as additional field.

```
 TVdatepick.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            filter(s.toString());
        }
 private void filter(String text)
{
    List<model> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (model item : datalist) {
        if (item.getPunchDate().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())) {
            filteredList.add(item);
        }
    }

    adapter.filterList(filteredList);
}
```

Adapter class:

```
  public void filterList(List<model> filteredList) {
    this.datalist=filteredList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```