# Trying to order Firestore results in query

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a query that I would like to order by a start date and filter by end date.

```js
return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("content")
        .where("active", isEqualTo: true)
        .where("end", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: DateTime.now())
        .orderBy("start", descending: true)
        .snapshots();
```

Error:

> The initial orderBy() field '[[FieldPath([start]), true]][0][0]' has to be the same as the where() field parameter 'FieldPath([end])' when an inequality operator is invoked.

Answer (score 3):

> If you include a filter with a range comparison (<, <=, >, >=), your first ordering must be on the same field

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#limitations

So you should go with

```
return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("content")
        .where("active", isEqualTo: true)
        .where("end", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: DateTime.now())
        .orderBy("end", descending: true)
        .orderBy("start", descending:true)
        .snapshots();
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. So if I want them sorted in ascending order by start ... how would that be? Right now they're not ordered correctly. I tried your code and also changed `.orderBy("start", descending:false)`, created the indexes, but still not ordered correctly.

Comment: Yeah ... not working. Tried multiple orderBy but still not ordered in `ascending` order by `start`.

Comment: Well, you should use the field `start` in a `where` clause so you can `orderBy` using only the `start`. You could search for `start <= DateTime.now() && end >= DateTime.now()`. Guess all your starts are before the end so then you can `orderBy start`

Comment: That would mean that it will only show started events. And I don't want that. I need to show upcoming events up to the end date. Some events span across multiple days/weeks/months. So an event has to be viewable until its end date.

Comment: Well, either you find out how can you work with the `end` and `start` parameters so you can use the `start` as an `orderBy` parameter, or you save the result in a list and throw out of that what you don't need...

Comment: Yeah ... I think I need to do that. I just thought that it can be done when making the query.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the following error:

> The initial orderBy() field '[[FieldPath([start]), true]][0][0]' has to be the same as the where() field parameter 'FieldPath([end])' when an inequality operator is invoked.

Because there is no way you can get data from Firestore without first sorting on the `end` field when using an inequality operator. So you need to reorder the results in your application code. So after calling:

```
.where("end", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: DateTime.now())
```

It's mandatory to call:

```
.orderBy("end", descending:false)
```

So your query should look like this:

```
return FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("content")
    .where("active", isEqualTo: true)
    .where("end", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: DateTime.now())
    .orderBy("end", descending:false)
    .orderBy("start", descending:true)
    .snapshots();
```

Don't also forget to create an [index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305328/firestore-whereequalto-orderby-and-limit1-not-working) in order to make this query work.

Comment: I don't think I can use `ascending` and I did try `end - descending false` and `start decending true`

Comment: Sorry, my bad, it should be `descending:false`. What was the result when using that combination? Have you created the correct index?

Comment: Yeah. Tried that combination. But it's not being ordered. I will grab everything and then just order in the app. For now. I will investigate further. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: Did you further investigate? Is there everything alright?

Comment: Hi. I did, but it wasn't working for me so I just ordered after grabbing the data like I said in the above comment.

Comment: So you solve it by ordering on the client, right?

Comment: Yes. That's what I did.

Comment: Did my answer help you?