# Combining where and orderBy clauses in Firestore Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am breaking my head over this problem for several days. The documentation says there is a limitation to use where with equality and orderBy clauses in a single query - https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data

My code is as follows:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('users')
                .where('uid', isNotEqualTo: user.uid)
                .orderBy('accountCreationDate', descending: false)
                .snapshots()
```

I have also created a composite index according to other answers in SO
[image]

but I am getting this error

```
"The initial orderBy() field \"[[FieldPath([accountCreationDate]), false]][0][0]\" has to be the
same as the where() field parameter \"FieldPath([uid])\" when an inequality operator is invoked."
The relevant error-causing widget was:
  StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>
```

Based on the suggestion made by others, the best way to achieve my goal is to sort at a front-end level. My issue is I don't really know how to tell the program that an object returned from the firestore snapshot is of type User. The code for user model is below

```
lass User implements Comparable {
  final String user_name;
  final String uid;
  final String email;
  final List followers;
  final List following;
  final String pictureUrl;
  final List bookmarks;
  final DateTime accountCreationDate;

  const User(
      {required this.email,
      required this.uid,
      required this.user_name,
      required this.pictureUrl,
      required this.followers,
      required this.following,
      required this.bookmarks,
      required this.accountCreationDate});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'user_name': user_name,
        'uid': uid,
        'email': email,
        'pictureUrl': pictureUrl,
        'followers': followers,
        'following': following,
        'bookmarks': bookmarks,
        'accountCreationDate': accountCreationDate
      };

  static User fromSnap(DocumentSnapshot snap) {
    var snapshot = snap.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    return User(
        email: snapshot['email'],
        user_name: snapshot['user_name'],
        uid: snapshot['uid'],
        pictureUrl: snapshot['pictureUrl'],
        followers: snapshot['followers'],
        following: snapshot['following'],
        bookmarks: snapshot['bookmarks'],
        accountCreationDate: snapshot['accountCreationDate'].toDate());
  }

  @override
  int compareTo(other) {
    if (accountCreationDate.isAfter(other.accountCreationDate)) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return -1;
    }
  }
}
```

This is what I am trying to do

```
body: StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('users')
                .where('uid', isNotEqualTo: user.uid)
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (context,
                AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting ||
                  !snapshot.hasData) {
                return const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
              List sortedUsers = snapshot.data!.docs.map((a,b)=> a.compareTo(b))
...
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to adapt your index but I saw some sources that stated the following should work:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
   .collection('users')
   .where('uid', isNotEqualTo: user.uid)
   .orderBy("uid", descending:false)
   .orderBy('accountCreationDate', descending: false)
.snapshots()
```

The second solution would be to save the snapshot to a list and filter it there without using firebase sdk

Please see this source for more info on your firebase problem:

[Trying to order Firestore results in query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68917097/trying-to-order-firestore-results-in-query?rq=1)

Also for users coming across that here is the firebase documentation regarding using where and orderBy:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#limitations

https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries?hl=de

Comment: thanks @ Enviro Apps, you and Dev suggested the same approach, but surprisingly it doesn't work - nothing is returned from the firestore. Also it doesn't really solve my issue of sorting by accountCreationDate field, but thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

As per error the condition field should appear in order by also so Use

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('users')
                .where('uid', isNotEqualTo: user.uid)
                .orderBy('uid')
                .orderBy('accountCreationDate', descending: false)
                .snapshots()
```

Just see if it works.

Now the main part comes that its not ordered by `accountCreationDate` which you have to handle at client side. That is sort on flutter side using `accountCreationDate` field

At client side use (Also you  don't need  implements Comparable)

```
List sortedUsers = snapshot.data!.docs.map((a,b)=> a.compareTo(b))

 sortedUsers.sort((a,b)=> a.accountCreationDate.compareTo(b.accountCreationDate));
```

Comment: yeap, I think you're right - the only viable option is to sort on the client side. I am still a newbie with regards to Flutter. Can you suggest what is the right approach to do that? I've tried this 
snapshot.data!.docs..sort((a,b)=> a.compareTo(b)); but I don't get how a program should understand that a and b of a certain type and they support compareTo method. The type of snapshot is AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>

Comment: By your code I can't tell if you use a Model class or what version of Firestore but this is how a sort function could look like:

users.sort((a,b) {
 var adate = a['accountCreationDate'];
 var bdate = b['accountCreationDate'];
 return adate.compareTo(bdate);
});

Comment: updated the original post with the model class

Comment: check the updated solution for client part