# How can I filter and sort my documents in Firestore RecylerView (Firestore UI)?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I want to sort and filter my documents like the below code. But it didn't work. Actually, when I add a new document I can't see it in real-time.

```
val query: Query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            .collection("Lessons")
            .whereEqualTo("tag",tag)
            .orderBy("order",Query.Direction.ASCENDING)


        val options: FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Model> = FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Model>()
            .setQuery(query, Model::class.java)
            .build()

        adapter = KonuRecyclerAdapter(options,tag,konuBasligi)
        binding?.konularAnaRecyclerView?.adapter = adapter
```

But when I comment "whereEqualto" line I can see new documents (Newly added). After that, if I uncomment this line again, I can see this document too. I want that when I add a new document it will show in real-time. Please help me with this problem. You can warn me of any mistakes that I did. Any help will be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell you are trying to use a Query that contains a call to:

```
.whereEqualTo("tag",tag)
```

And

```
.orderBy("order",Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
```

On a different field. This kind of query requires an index. To see how you can solve this, please see my answer from the following post:

- [Firestore whereEqualTo, orderBy and limit(1) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305328/firestore-whereequalto-orderby-and-limit1-not-working)

However, using a call to `.whereEqualTo()` without an ordering or, a call to `.orderBy()` without a `.whereEqualTo()` call, doesn't require an index. That's the reason why it's working when you comment one, or the other method calls.

Comment: But when I want to create these indexes, it looks like tag Ascending order Ascending, but my "tag" fields are all the same. Why this filter (tag) looks "Ascending" ???

Comment: When you aren't specifying the order and a direction when using the "tag" field in your query, the default (ascending) one is set. If you need however another order, you should consider adding an extra order by "tag" call.

Comment: I think, you misunderstand me. My documents are like that; "lesson" = "Math", "tag" = "numerical" //// "lesson" = "Science", "tag" = "numerical" ///// "lesson" = "Literature", "tag" = "verbal"/////"lesson" = "History", "tag" = "verbal". I want to do filter these documents by tag not ordering. What I meant is filtering. Did you get me now? Thank you for your help

Comment: I understood pretty well what you are trying to say. Even if you don't create an explicit order "by tag", when you are using `.whereEqualTo("tag",tag)` and you create an index, **the ordering by tag it's automatically added**, with the default ascending direction. You cannot change that. Is it clear now?

Comment: So, what I understand is that it will work fine, isn't it? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: For sure it will.