# How i can query my subCollection on firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I wanna query only the users with the subcollection Favoris (not everyUsers had a favoris subcollection) and I wanna query only the document from favoris with the same id as the current user.

I did the following function but I have no document found. I'm supposed to have one. Did I forget something?

```js
const getFavoris = () => {
  userDB.doc()
        .collection('favoris')
        .where('id', '==', currentUser.id)
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
          console.log('cmb', querySnapshot.size);
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            console.log(doc.id);
          });
        });
};
```

also an example of my DB user and subcollection Favoris

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since "favoris" is a subcollection, instead of using a [collection()](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/firestore#collection) call, you should use a [collectionGroup()](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/firestore#collectionGroup) query like in the following lines of code:

```
const getFavoris = () => {
      firebase.firestore()
      .collectionGroup('favoris') //
      .where('id', '==', currentUser.id)
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        console.log('cmb', querySnapshot.size);
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          console.log(doc.id);
        });
      });
  };
```

Besides that, don't forget to create the corresponding [index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305328/firestore-whereequalto-orderby-and-limit1-not-working).

Comment: Can you help me with the rootRef ? what is it exactly ?

Comment: I just edited my answer. Does it work now?

Comment: yes i have just this comment , they ask me to add an exception, which i did and now i have this promise rejection : ossible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
FirebaseError: The query requires a COLLECTION_GROUP_ASC index for collection favoris and field id. That index is not ready yet.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I just updated my answer.

Comment: i don't understad how to create my index, i'm new with firestore :(

Comment: Try to find a URL in the error message, or create it manually in the Firebase console. It should be a collection group index with an ascending direction (COLLECTION_GROUP_ASC).

Comment: it's ok, it's working !! thank you for everything :)

Comment: last question ? How i can do if i wanna catch all the information of the user with favoris ?(to go back on the collection )

Comment: You should then perform separate queries. All queries in Firestore are shallow, it can only get documents from the collection that the query is run against.