# Firestore - getting entries using 2 columns

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a `meeting` collections with documents like:

```
{
name: John
date: 1 Jan 2021
time: 10am
meeting note: morning standup
}
```

I want to get documents with say `name=John`, and dates after today.

Since Firestore does not support query using two fields, I suppose I need to get `name=John` and filter myself for dates after today? If yes, is there a more efficient and effective way to do that?

Comment: Why would you say it doesn't support queries using two fields? As long as you create the corresponding [index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305328/firestore-whereequalto-orderby-and-limit1-not-working), it indeed does, right?

Answer (score 1):

While there are [limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations) on the types of queries that Firestore can perform, this one seems well within its limits. In JavaScript it'd be:

```
import { query, where } from "firebase/firestore";  

const q1 = query(citiesRef, where("nam", "==", "John"), where("date", ">=", new Date()));
```

If the query doesn't immediately return results, check the log output as you may need to create a compound index on the two fields. The log output in that case will contain an error message with a direct link to create the index (with the fields already filled in).

Also see the documentation on [compound queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries).