# Firestore compound query not returning data

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I try to fetch data from Firestore with a `whereGreaterThan` and whereArrayContains compound query. For some reason, this combination does not seem to work. If I omit one of the two statements they work and return almost the same data.

```
    someCollection
        ?.whereGreaterThan("date", Date().startOfPreviousMonth)
        ?.whereArrayContains("ids", id)
        ?.get()
        ?.addOnSuccessListener { .... }
        ?.addOnFailureListener { .... }
```

In the documentation it is only stated that there are only these restrictions for compound queries:

> Limitations
>
> Note the following limitations for != queries:
>
> - Only documents where the given field exists can match the query.
> - You can't combine not-in and != in a compound query.
> - In a compound query, range (<, <=, >, >=) and not equals (!=, not-in) comparisons must all filter on the same field.

For me, no one of these matches my problem. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way you can use `whereGreaterThan()` and `whereArrayContains()` method calls in the same query without creating an [index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305328/firestore-whereequalto-orderby-and-limit1-not-working).

Create the corresponding index, either manually in the Firebase Console or automatically by clicking the link in the Android Studio logcat.

In Android, you can attach a Failure listener and get the URL from the error message.

Comment: yes it helped me a lot. thank you. Probably you could update your answer that the addOnFailureListener returns a link how to set that index if it is missing. This will probably help a lot of people in the future :)

Comment: Indeed. I just updated my answer.