# How to update Firestore RecyclerView Adapter based upon field value changes locally or in database?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I'm trying to reload or update Firestore Recyclerview Adapter (Firebase Ui) based upon field value changes.

In my case I'm querying `.whereNotIn("id", list)` where list is stored locally and updated frequently which should trigger firestore recyclerview options based upon arraylist value updated.

My code is below:

```
 postsRef
                .orderBy("id")
                .whereNotIn("id", list) // list is updated frequently so update firesttore recyclervew option
                .whereEqualTo("disabled", false)
                .whereEqualTo("expired", false)
                .whereEqualTo("locality", locality)
                .whereEqualTo("country", country)
                .orderBy("createdAt", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                .limit(20)

        val firestoreRecyclerOptions: FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Post> =
            FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Post>()
                .setQuery(query, Post::class.java)
                .build()
```

"list" value is changes locally frequently. I want to update firestore RecyclerView options maybe reload based upon list update.

Comment: So what's wrong with this code? Have you created an  [index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305328/firestore-whereequalto-orderby-and-limit1-not-working)?

Comment: I'm storing ArrayList value as list locally which is used to query database. Firestore trigger based upon database changes. But I want to update Firestore Recyclerview options based upon local list is updated frequently without recreating Fragment. Yes I have created an index.

Answer (score 0):

The list is updated as the data in the table is updated.

The code I wrote for myself, you can change it according to you.

```
docRef
                    .whereEqualTo(field, equel)
                    .whereEqualTo(cevapField, cevapdurum)
                    .orderBy("date",query)
                    .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, firebaseFirestoreException ->
                        firebaseFirestoreException?.let {
                            Toast.makeText(context, it.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show()
                           //error
                            return@addSnapshotListener
                        }
                        val listData: MutableList<Any> = mutableListOf()
                        querySnapshot?.let {
                            for (document in it) {
                               //success
                                val data1=document.getString("data1")
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: In my case "list" is stored locally. I want to update Firestore UI RecyclerAdapter without re-creating fragment.

Comment: Ben de fragment içinde rcyclerView kullanarak yapıyorum. fragment yeniden oluşturmadan güncelleniyor

Comment: This is how i do it and i can view my list even without internet.even I'm making a query, sorting by date or because the question was answered, not answered and all.ı don't have any comments for you unfortunately.For support 
can you click the up arrow

Comment: I am also doing it using cyclerView inside fragment. updating fragment without rebuilding.