# getting null error when using .where('uid', isEqualTo: uid) in firebase flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, android-studio, dart, null

we are making home page like Instagram and I want to show only the user post for now.
the code was like this

```
 StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('posts').orderBy("datePublished", descending: true).snapshots(),
    builder: (context,
        AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
         return const Center(
             child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
         );
      }
    return PageView.builder(/*the rest of the code ...*/);
```

it worked but it shows all the post so I added this

```
.where('uid', isEqualTo: uid)
```

and it looks like this
inside Widget build

```
var uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
```

inside body like this

```
StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('posts').where('uid', isEqualTo: uid).orderBy("datePublished", descending: true).snapshots(),
    builder: (context,
        AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
         return const Center(
             child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
         );
      }
    return PageView.builder( //to make the page scroll
      itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,/*the rest of the code*/);
```

and it shows an error in line

> itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
> saying `Null check operator used on a null value`

the database look like this

[image]

Comment: Have you created the corresponding [index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305328/firestore-whereequalto-orderby-and-limit1-not-working)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that `snapshot.data` is `null`. This could happen when `snapshot.connectionState` is equal to `ConnectionState.none` when the stream is initialized and should be protected against.

Depending on how the PageView is set up you could handle this by changing that line to
`itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs.length ?? 0,`
which will pass 0 when `snapshot.data` is null.

Another way would be to check for the null value beforehand.

```
if (snapshot.data == null) {
    return SomeWidget():
} else {
    return PageView.builder( //to make the page scroll
      itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,/*the rest of the code*/
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much. I tried this (itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs.length ?? 0) and it worked <3