# Query firestore array of objects..?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i have a firestore collection thats structured like this:[firestore collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRuxo.png)

and i am trying to query as follows:
`await db.collection('users').where("company.id", "==", company).where("profiles.default.dailyQuestion", "array-contains", {questionId: 'MwIGtFpz8qzVxJEW5TWc'}).get()`

i believe that i am approaching it correctly but it is returning no data from firestore.  am i missing something obvious?

Comment: Maybe an [index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305328/firestore-whereequalto-orderby-and-limit1-not-working)?

Comment: See the duplicate: It is not possible, with array-contains, to query for a specific property of an object stored in an array. However, there is a possible workaround: it is actually possible to query for the entire object.