# Is there a way to filter multiple fields in Firebase Firestore in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, filter

I am trying to have multiple inequality filters on multiple fields in my Firebase Firestore collection to be able to search for certain properties on certain criteria, but Firebase Firestore doesn't allow this for no obvious or acceptable reason. What I want to know is if there is a way to achieve what I am trying to do but with a different methodology.

for example i want to filter my properties based on price and number of bed rooms so i would write something like  `.where("price",">=",price).where("bedrooms",">="bedrooms)`

But of course, Firebase and its unlimited limitations don't allow us to do something as simple as this. So, is there a way I can overcome this?

Here is my code:

```
 const search = () => {

    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("Properties")
      .where("location", "==", address)
      .where("bedrooms", "==", rooms)
      .where("category", "==", category)
      .where("price", ">=", price)
      .where("type","==", type)
      .get()
      .then((result) => {
        if (result.size == 0) {
          // Toast.fire({
          //   icon: "error",
          //   title: "No properties were found, please modify your search",
          // });
        } else {
            setPropertyCount(result.size);
            const properties = result.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
            setSearchData(properties);
        }
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the following query will not work:

```
.where("price",">=",price).where("bedrooms",">="bedrooms)
```

Because of the limitation that is mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations):

> In a compound query, range (<, <=, >, >=) and not equals (!=, not-in) comparisons must all filter on the same field.

So if you try to perform this query, you'll get an error message that sounds like this:

> All where filters with an inequality (notEqualTo, notIn, lessThan, lessThanOrEqualTo, greaterThan, or greaterThanOrEqualTo) must be on the same field. But you have filters on 'price' and 'bedrooms'

But that is happening not to upset you, but to guarantee performance. In order to massively scale, there are some limitations that we should take into consideration.

> So, is there a way I can overcome this?

Yes, there is. There is a technique called denormalization. So I recommend you check my answer from the following post:

- [What is denormalization in Firebase Cloud Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54258303/what-is-denormalization-in-firebase-cloud-firestore)

So if you're new to NoSQL databases, that might sound some kind of weird, but it will help us solve this kind of problem. So in your case, I would create a collection for each type of apartment (one bedroom, two bedrooms, etc.) and I would query like this:

```
firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("twoBedrooms")
    .where("price",">=",price)
```

Case in which there are no limitations. If you need more such filters, please also don't forget to create an [index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305328/firestore-whereequalto-orderby-and-limit1-not-working).

Comment: Also, noSQL seems to go backwards in every way that SQL progresses and is a really solid and structured query language and database such as mySQL. in SQL we learn NORMALIZATION and in noSQL we are told to DENORMALIZE our database? its really upsetting and disappointing to see these kind of database marketed as the next big thing when theyre really expensive and extremely limited that you cant even create a filter query or a search query.