# Recycler no longer responsive after adding Firebase query

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

My app shows a `Firebase db` through a `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter`. I have put the code relating to the `query` in a separate `method`:

```
private void queryActive(){

    queryActive = collectionRef
            .whereEqualTo("activeStatus",1);                

}
```

Each `item` in the `recycler` display has a `switch` through which the status of the underlying item's `int` `field` "activeStatus" can be toggled between "active" (1) and  "inactive" (0).

The app shows indeed only the items that are "active". If I toggle the switch of a certain item to "inactive", that item indeed disappears. Excellent.

Now I want to order the active items according to their `int` `field` "categoryNumber". So I add an `orderBy()` method.

```
private void queryActive(){

        queryActive = collectionRef
                .whereEqualTo("activeStatus",1)
                .orderBy("categoryNumber", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);

}
```

I understand that, as `Firebase` automatically adds a `simple index` for every field, there is no need to manually add an index. After all I'm not using `composite indexes`.

When I run the app, the active items are now ranked according to "categoryNumber", as intended. BUT the **switch buttons of all items have become irresponsive**. Checking in Firebase, the "1" indeed has nowhere been changed to "0", after trying to toggle the switches.

*How is it possible that a switch button in the items' recycler cards becomes irresponsive after adding a `simple index` ordering expression to the query?*

Answer (score 0):

Such a query:

```
queryActive = collectionRef
        .whereEqualTo("activeStatus",1)
        .orderBy("categoryNumber", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);
```

Indeed requires an [index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305328/firestore-whereequalto-orderby-and-limit1-not-working). So once you run the code, check the logcat of Android Studio for the link. If somehow you don't find it, create the index manually in the Firebase console.

Besides that, in my opinion, it makes more sense to set the type of the `activeStatus` field to be Boolean rather than a number. So the above query looks better like this:

```
queryActive = collectionRef
        .whereEqualTo("activeStatus", true) //
        .orderBy("categoryNumber", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);
```

Comment: Thanks, again, Alex. I had rewritten the entire app so that it avoids using "composite indices" (I understand, that means ordering along more than one field), as these indeed have to be manually enabled in the collection, in Firebase itself. Are you saying that a combination of a whereEqualTo() and a single orderBy() also constitute a "composite index", and therefore requires manual indexing?

Comment: Yes, that combination requires an index.

Comment: Hey Jonathan. Can I help you with other information?