# Why the data from firebase database is not showing in my recyclerview while searching?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

MainActivity.kt Code

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
val db = Firebase.firestore
    val firebaseFirestore : FirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()


    private var searchList: List<dataClass> = ArrayList()
    private val adapter = adapter(searchList)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        supportActionBar?.hide()

        val search_list :RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.search_list)

        search_list.hasFixedSize()
        search_list.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
         search_list.adapter = adapter

        binding.searchField.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher{
            override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {

            }

     override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
val search : String = binding.searchField.text.toString()
                //Search in Firestore
                searchInFirestore(search.toLowerCase())
            }

   override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {

            }

        })
}

    private fun searchInFirestore(search: String) {
        firebaseFirestore.collection("mechanic").orderBy("city").startAt(search).endAt("$search\uf8ff").get()
            .addOnCompleteListener {
            if(it.isSuccessful){
                searchList = it.result!!.toObjects(dataClass::class.java)
                adapter.searchlist =searchList
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

            }
                else{
                    Log.d(TAG,"Error:${it.exception!!.message}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Adapter.kt code

```
class adapter(var searchlist: List<dataClass> ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<adapter.viewholder>(){


    inner class viewholder(itemView: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val mname: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name)
        val mphone : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.phone)
        val addres: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.address)
        fun bind(dataClass: dataClass){
            mname.text = dataClass.name
            mphone.text = dataClass.phone
            addres.text = dataClass.address
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): viewholder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.single_search,parent,false)
        return viewholder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: viewholder, position: Int) {
holder.bind(searchlist[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return searchlist.size
    }
}
```

the view in which i have to bind data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.022" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Phone no"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/phone"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="144dp"
        android:layout_height="19dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/address"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.088"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Address"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/address"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="86dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.229"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Mainactivity.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_field"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:paddingTop="20sp"
        android:text="Search here"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="408dp"
        android:layout_height="642dp"
        android:id="@+id/search_list"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/search_field" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

i want to implement a live search view in my app using firestore database but when i running the above code it doesn't showing any thing to me. I think there is a mistake in my adapter.kt and mainactivity.kt file. Please help me to correct it.

[image: App image nothing is showing]

[image]

I am expecting to see the data while searching but it is not showing the data from firestore. I want it to be appear in search result.

dataclass.kt `data class dataClass ( val name: String ="",val phone:String = "", val address : String ="" )`

Comment: Have you created an [index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305328/firestore-whereequalto-orderby-and-limit1-not-working)?

Comment: No, but I created it after your comment and still it's not showing anything.

Comment: I think there's a mistake in binding the data. And i am not able to solve it. If you have reference for implementing a live search view like i am trying to make then please share it.

Comment: If you understand Java, then this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-filter-firestore-data-cheaper-705f5efec444) will most likely help. For Kotlin and Jetpack Compose, check [this](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-filter-firestore-in-real-time-using-jetpack-compose-952abaab15c5) out.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you're setting content to `binding` and then not referencing the RecyclerLayout from that binding. Try using `val search_list = binding.searchList` instead of `val search_list :RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.search_list)`