# How can I combine a WHERE and ORDERBY request in Firestore (Firebase 9)? ReactJs

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have following function. If I only use orderBy or where, it works and I receive the documents.
If I try to combine both, I receive null. Is it not possible to combine it like I did?

```
 const {documents} = useCollection('users', ['name', '==', 'Tom'] ,['age', 'asc'])
```

```
export const useCollection = (collections, _q, _ordBy) => {
    const [documents, setDocuments] = useState(null)
    const [error, setError] = useState(null)
    const q = useRef(_q).current
    const ordBy = useRef(_ordBy).current

    useEffect(()=>{
        let ref = collection(db, collections)

        ref = query(ref, where(...q), orderBy(...ordBy))

        const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(ref, (snapshot)=>{
            let results = []
            snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
                results.push({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})
            })
            setDocuments(results)
            setError(null)
        }, (error) => {
            setError('could not fetch')
        })
        return () => unsubscribe()
    }, [collections, q, ordBy])
    return {documents, error}
}
```

I tried only orderBy and only where and it works. After combining it, I receive null.

Comment: Yes, you can. But you have to create an [index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305328/firestore-whereequalto-orderby-and-limit1-not-working).

Comment: I also need to create indexes, if I only have one column in the orderBy? I created an index and it still does not work.

Comment: Yes, you need to create an index.

Comment: An index that includes name and age?

Comment: Yes, check the duplicate to see how you can create one. Or even better check the docs.

Comment: Thank, now it works. My index setting were wrong.