# Firestore - Query by field in array with java

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have data in Firestore like this:

[image]

And I want to query it **from Java** to *get all orders where any item status would be equal to TEST*. Is it possible?

It works fine when I get all orders from client like:

```
CollectionReference ordersRef = dbFirestore.collection("orders");    
Query query = ordersRef.whereEqualTo("client", "client1");
```

But I couldn't do it as I need. I try this

```
CollectionReference ordersRef = dbFirestore.collection("orders");    
Query query = ordersRef.whereEqualTo("items.status", "TEST");
```

but it returns an empty array

---

**UPDATE AFTER [ALEX'S ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76659045/5441668)**

---

If I convert items in a Map like:
[image]
then this query works fine

```
Query query = ordersRef.whereEqualTo("orders.items.status", "TEST");
```

but this doesn´t resolve the problem because the items Map need to have several objects like
[image]

--

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And I want to query it from Java to get all orders where any item status would be equal to TEST. Is it possible?

That's currently not possible. You cannot query a collection based on a value that exists within objects that exist in an array field. You could however query using an entire object and call [Query#whereArrayContains()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query#whereArrayContains(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object)). So instead of trying to query based only on the value of `status` you have queried based on an object that contains all three fields. Besides that, the following query would have worked:

```
Query query = ordersRef.whereEqualTo("client.items.status", "TEST");
```

If that data would have been added as a map (object) and not as an array.

However, to solve such a problem you should consider creating a sub-collection called `items` inside each document. In this way, a query like this should do the trick:

```
Query queryByStatus = dbFirestore.collectionGroup("orders").whereEqualTo("status", "TEST");
```

When using such a query, please also don't forget to create an [index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305328/firestore-whereequalto-orderby-and-limit1-not-working).

Why would you use this solution? Simply because there are no limitations. When you store lots of objects inside an array, you might hit the [maximum limit of  1 Mib](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#limits) per document.

Comment: hi Alex, I dont understand the sub-collection approach. Should I create a new collection called items and reference it inside orders.items?

Comment: By sub-collection I mean, instead of adding those items separately inside the array, get the array out of the document and add the exact item as a separate document in a sub-collection that belongs to the document. Is it clear now?