# firebase generic filtering needs indexes for each combination

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following code to query properties (paginated) with filters:

```
const propertyCollectionRef = db.collection('properties')

    let queryRef = propertyCollectionRef;

    let query: any = db.collection('properties');

    if (filters) {
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(filters)) {
            if (key !== 'page') {
                switch (key) {
                    case "price":
                        query = query.where(key, '<=', parseInt(value));
                        break;
                    case "bathrooms":
                        query = query.where(key, '==', parseInt(value));
                        break;
                    case "beds":
                        query = query.where(key, '==', parseInt(value));
                        break;
                    case "min-area":
                        query = query.where("area", '>=', parseInt(value));
                        break;
                    case "max-area":
                        query = query.where("area", '<=', parseInt(value));
                        break;
                    case "typ":
                        query = query.where(key, '==', value);
                        break;
                    default:
                        query = query.where(key, '==', value);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }



    const offset = (page - 1) * pageSize

    const querySnapshot = await query
        .limit(pageSize)
        .offset(offset).get();
```

firebase wants me to create an index for each query combination (

```
code: 9,
  details: 'The query requires an index. You can create it here:...
```

) made when choosing different filters, for example, I need to create one for filtering `price` and `type`. but also one when filtering for `price`, `type`, and `bathrooms`

how is it possible to make this more "generic" - I can't think of firebase to make it such complicated...

Comment: What's the problem in creating an index for each combination? You can create up to [200 indexes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#indexes).

Comment: that is alone with 4 filters a huge effort... can not imagine that this should be the way... Especially for the maintainability...

Comment: The [indexes are created automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305328/firestore-whereequalto-orderby-and-limit1-not-working). Besides that, queries like yours cannot work without creating indexes.

Comment: the indexes are created automatically but still requires me to click on the link ... i just found out that the query won't work in firestore "In a compound query, range (<, <=, >, >=) and not equals (!=, not-in) comparisons must all filter on the same field." ->

Comment: is it really so that the most queries only use one range filter and do the rest client side... ?

Comment: What are the possible values for `filters`? Can the keys be anything? Moreover you wont be able to do a range query on `area` and `price` - only one is allowed

Comment: the keys are defined in an interface so not anything is allowed. yes i've already recognized that its not possible to use several range filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i will answer the question by my own and maybe for somebody who is also stepping across this situation:

in general its not possible to filter a collection as i did as in a in a compound query, range (<, <=, >, >=) and not equals (!=, not-in) comparisons must all filter on the same field - in my case i needed it for four range filter fields.

after checking the docs and some other repos i saw that in my situation it is the best to use only one range filter for the geoposition, to make this happen i use GeoFire which uses geohashes so only one field is required for the range filter. Please check out this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mx1mMdHBi5Q) it is explained brilliant how to query for geopoints in firebase

```
let query: any = propertyCollectionRef.near({ center: new firestore.GeoPoint(lat, lng
        ), radius: radius });
```

i use then one more "equal" filter to decrease the loaded data  with the rent type (for rent, for sale) ...

the rest of the range filters price, bathrooms, beds, ... are applied client side with a simpel `if/else`

it's the best way i've found so far to handle my query

Answer (score 0):

> Firebase wants me to create an index for each query combination.

Cloud Firestore guarantees the query performance by requiring an index for every query. The indexes required for the most basic queries are automatically created for you. There is nothing that you should do. However, for more complex queries like yours, an index is required. One thing to notice is that you can create up to [200 indexes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#indexes). If you need more than 200, then you can contact [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support) to request an increase to this limit.

Besides that, the [indexes are created automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305328/firestore-whereequalto-orderby-and-limit1-not-working). So that being said, queries like yours cannot work without creating indexes.

> The indexes are created automatically but still require me to click on the link.

Yes, that's correct. If you don't want to do that yourself by clicking the URLs or by creating the indexes directly in the Firebase Console, then you should consider using the [Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing#use_the_firebase_cli). This allows you to deploy indexes with the [Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli) very easily.

> Is it really so that most queries only use one range filter and do the rest client side?

For such queries, yes, here is a [list of all query limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations) in Firestore.

Comment: Hey Jul. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your answer. i just posted my solution with an answer, i'm open for any feedback or better solutions :) in general the indexes solution wouldn't solve my query as it is only allowed to use one range filter field...

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to create a single index that includes all the filters you might need, rather than creating a new index for each possible combination. eg:

```
propertyCollectionRef
    .where("price", "<=", argument)
    .where("bathrooms", "==", argument)
    .where("beds", "==", argument)
    .where("area", ">=", argument)
    .where("type", "==", argument)
```

This would cover all the possible combinations of filters and allow you to query for any combination without having to create multiple indexes.

Comment: it is not possible to use multiple range filters , so it is no option.