# How should I store data in Firestore for a logging app?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I am working on a web app using React and Firebase Firestore. The app lets users log the skills they learn each day and how long they learn. The current structure of my database is just a single collection where the documents are individual logs. A document looks like this:

```
// document in collection 'logs'
createdAt: timestamp
hours: number
minutes: number
notes: string
skill: string
uid: string
```

The logs are displayed as a table, so when the user loads into the dashboard I run this query to get their logs:

```
const logsRefQuery = query(
    collection(db, 'logs'),
    where('uid', '==', user?.uid || null),
    orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
)
```

The things I would like to be able to do with the database data are:

1. Being able to sort the table by different fields (Skill, date created, time spent). If I want to do this right now it seems like I need a composite query for every combination of user id and the field to sort by.
2. Getting the total hours logged for each skill of the user
3. Getting the total hours of all skills logged on a certain day.

Is this possible with the current way I have the database set up?

Comment: These use-cases all sounds feasible to me on your current data model. I recommend just giving it a try, and posting back with a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if/when you run into problems.

Comment: I am currently trying to make the composite indexes for the fields I want to order by. I am running the same query I originally posted except that createdAt is replaced by hours. Firestore isn't throwing an error with the link to make the composite index and instead returns undefined when I run the query. I have no composite indexes in the database at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the same way you're filtering the users by the UID, you can also do it with any other fields. And yes, it's true, if you want to perform multiple filtering and ordering, indeed an [index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305328/firestore-whereequalto-orderby-and-limit1-not-working) is required.
2. To solve that, you should read the document that corresponds to a user and use the following formula:

   ```
   var total = hours + minutes/60
   ```
3. Since you already have a field of type timestamp, to get the total hours of all skills logged on a certain day, for example to 19 November, you have to pass to the `startAt()` function a Date object that represents `2023-11-19 00:00:00` and to the `endAt()` function ta Date object that represents `2023-11-19 23:59:59`. So it's a combination between these two methods.

Comment: Hey Collin. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?