# How to notify FirestorePagingAdapter?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I am using `FirestorePagingAdapter` for showing data from Firestore and paginate the data. I want to refresh the adapter with new data when Firestore changes . `notifyDataSetChanged()` is not working when ever I want to notify data .currently I am calling this :

```
 public void setPaging(Query query) {
    FirestorePagingOptions<AddFabricModel> options = new FirestorePagingOptions.Builder<AddFabricModel>()
            .setLifecycleOwner(this)
            .setQuery(query, config, AddFabricModel.class)
            .build();
    adapter=new AllFabricsAdapter(context,options,this);
    rvAllFabrics.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

To notify the data I am passing the query then creating the adapter obj again which i dont want.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `FireStorePagingAdapter` in the Firebase-UI library to receive updates because is designed only to get data and not to listen for realtime updates. Inside the [FirestorePagingAdapter](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/firestore/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/firestore/paging/FirestorePagingAdapter.java) class, there is no `notifyDataSetChanged()` method so to solve this, you need to start listening for changes using:

```
adapter.startListening();
```

You can also take a look at my answer from  this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50741958/how-to-paginate-firestore-with-android)** where you can find an example on how to paginate queries by combining query cursors with the limit() method. I also recommend you take a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KdgKvLll07s)** for a better understanding.

Comment: Hey Alex, If I want to build a chat UI and I also want to let the users see old messages. Therefore, if I go with FirestorePagingOptions I have to load all the data or I can limit it. Is there a way to update real-time and also load the old data step by step :) using firestoreUI or any recommend method? :)

Comment: @IsuruBandara I think you might be interested in this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firestore-pagination-with-real-time-updates-ce05a87bb902).

Comment: That's what I wanted. Thank you for making useful articles on Medium :)

Answer (score 0):

just call com.firebase.ui.firestore.paging.FirestorePagingAdapter#refresh