# How to remove item from Firestore Paging Adapter?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui, android-paging

I am using Firestore Paging Adapter for loading a list of data and displaying it in RecyclerView. I set onClickListener on each item loaded and I would like to remove item from RecyclerView if it is pressed. How can I do that.
I get pressed item with

```
val pressedUserRealtion = getItem(adapterPosition)?.toObject(UserRelation::class.java)
```

and I would like to delete this item from my RecyclerView. I searched and couldn't find any method that would do that, I can't get the reference to list that contains loaded items. The only thing I can think of is setting the view visibility to GONE when user selects the item.

Comment: Do you want to remove the item from the database *and* the UI? Or only from the UI?

Comment: Well I do remove it from the database by executing cloud function which removes that document and also does other work. I know that there is FirestoreRecyclerAdapter which updates the recyclerView if new data is added, removed, changed but I would like to use FirestorePagingAdapter. Per documentation: "FirestoreRecyclerAdapter — binds a Query to a RecyclerView and responds to all real-time events included items being added, removed, moved, or changed. Best used with small result sets since all RESULTS ARE LOADED AT ONCE.". I have hundreds of rows of data so I want to use FirestorePagingAdapter

Comment: You say "Well I do remove it from the database by executing cloud function" so isn't also removed from the UI?

Comment: @AlexMamo I think the paging adapters in FirebaseUI don't auto-update, do they? If they don't, it'd need a page refresh.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Oh yes, you're right, I missed that. Actually I answered a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51175970/5246885) a year ago :) Btw, I'm looking forward to meed you in Madrid.

Answer (score 0):

for realtime update, you can use FirestoreRecyclerAdapter

> FirestoreRecyclerAdapter — binds a Query to a RecyclerView and
>   responds to all real-time events included items being added, removed,
>   moved, or changed. Best used with small result sets since all results
>   are loaded at once

[Documentation](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/firebaseui-android/firestore/readme/)