# Firestore descending pagination return 0 results when using ordeBy() and endBefore()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I was looking into Firebase Firestore and what better sample project to create than another chat app.

How I imagine it would work:

1. Newest messages are fetched when the user enters a fragment
2. update `oldestTimestamp`, add messages to recycler view
3. when user scrolls to top `fecthMore` and get 20 messages that are older than the current oldest one
4. update `oldestTimestamp`, add messages to recycler view

   After reading [order-limit-data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) and [query-cursors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) I came up with those solutions, sadly none of them worked.

I used `whereLessThanOrEqualTo("timestamp", previousOldestMessageTimestamp)` but this returned 0 messages

After that, I tried using `.orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING) .endBefore(previousOldestMessageTimestamp)` same result as before

Then I tried simplifying the query to just `.orderBy("timestamp") .endBefore(previousOldestMessageTimestamp)` which returned some messages but in the list were oldest messages in whole conversation

**What should I change to make it work properly (as every chat app)?**

Also can you explain difference between `whereLessThanOrEqualTo()` and `orderBy()` + `endBefore()`

Here is some context

```
private var previousOldestMessageTimestamp: Long = -1

private fun firstFetch(){
    //get oldest messages
    //update previousOldestMessageTimestamp to oldest message timestamp
}

 private fun fetchMore() {
    val conversationRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                                           .document("conversations")
                                           .collection("some_id")

    conversationRef
            .whereLessThan("timestamp", previousOldestMessageTimestamp) 
            //^ 0 messages

            .orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            .endBefore(previousOldestMessageTimestamp)
            //^ returns 0 messages 

            .orderBy("timestamp") 
            .endBefore(previousOldestMessageTimestamp)
            //^ returns messages but starts with oldest one,
            //not what I want

            .limit(20)
            .get().addOnCompleteListener { it: Task<QuerySnapshot!>
                val messages: List<Message> = it.result.map { it.toObject(Message::class.java) }
                println("I fetched ${messages.size} messages : $messages")

                if (messages.isNotEmpty()) {
                    previousOldestMessageTimestamp = *oldestMessage*.timestamp
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50741958/how-to-paginate-firestore-with-android)** solution?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes, but I had a problem going to different direction. I expected startAfter to work differently (as it was in realtimeDBS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like start/ end work differently than in real-time database so changing

```
.orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
.endBefore(previousOldestMessageTimestamp)
```

to

```
.orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
.startAfter(previousOldestMessageTimestamp)
```

made it work