# Save DocumentSnapshot for Pagination in Firestore android

Tags: android, pagination, google-cloud-firestore

> I am trying to implement pagination functionality in android. Each time activity starts **I want to fetch new 10 records from collection**.

Next time when I open the activity. **lastVisible (DocumentSnapshot )** must be saved in SharedPreference to get the new list.

```
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        //new code starts...
        Query first = null;

        if(new SharedPrefs(mContext).read("callForFristTime",true)){
            first = db.collection("questionCollection").whereEqualTo("questionType",1)
                    .orderBy("dateCreated")
                    .limit(numberOfQuestionFetched);

            new SharedPrefs(mContext).save("callForFristTime",false);
        }
        else{
            first = db.collection("questionCollection")
                    .whereEqualTo("questionType",1)
                    .orderBy("dateCreated")
                    .startAfter(lastVisible)//how could I save lastVisible
                    .limit(numberOfQuestionFetched);
        }
```

How to save DocumentSnapshot(lastVisible) in SharedPreference ?

**Or tell another approach to handle pagination..**

> Problem Solved [**following this approach**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52069594/iterating-firestore-android-collection-on-basis-of-id-or-attribute/52487607#52487607)

Comment: why not you add/save the query in sharedPreference or other any resource before closing the app? every when you open a app just get query string from and cast back to query and execute the event on it

Comment: You can't Serialize a DocumentSnapshot.  I'd look for another way to do this that doesn't require a full DocumentSnapshot that comes from somewhere other than a query itself.

Comment: **[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50741958/how-to-paginate-firestore-with-android)** is a recommended way in which you can paginate queries by combining query cursors with the limit() method. I also recommend you take a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KdgKvLll07s)** for more details.

Comment: Have you tried to implement the solution from my answer in that post?

Comment: Your solution also requires lastVisible. But the next time I open the activity I don't have access to the lastVisible item.

Comment: Yeah, your best bet is to store `lastVisible.get("dateCreated")` and `lastVisible.getId()` and then next time do `.orderBy("dateCreated").orderBy(FieldPath.documentId()).startAt(lastVisibleDateCreated, lastVisibleId)` . This is functionally equivalent to using the lastVisible snapshot.