# Reduce number of read in Firestore Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

> I want to reduce number of reads in order to get Question's detail from `QuestionCollection` (Array of Questions) .

**My app works like a part of stackoverflow**.

I want to show how many **likes, views and comments do a question have** . So in order to handle this I created multiple collection like

**QuestionCollection**

- ID
- Title
- DateCreated

**CommentCollection**

- ID
- Comment
- DateCreated

**QuestionLikes**

- QuestionID
- UserID

**QuestionViews**

- QuestionID
- UserID

**QuestionTAG**

- QuestionID
- TagID

I thought that **CommentCollection** (comments) only belongs to a question. So I am thinking of incorporating in `QuestionCollection` like an array(s) or collection(But it requires another read hit). **which one is better** ?

And I think of adding two variable's(`totalViews,totalLikes`) to QuestionCollection. But each time I must have to check whether this question is liked by this user or view by this user.

Give me a suggestion or an alternative **so I can have the least hit to fetch question details**.

**Edit**

**For Showing View Count** 
    I iterate and count **QuestionViews Collection** where questionID  == myQuestionID

**For Showing Likes Count** 
    I iterate and count **QuestionLikes Collection** where questionID  == myQuestionID

why I don't add it to QuestionCollection? Because I want to show most Viewed and most like question like stackoverflow. If i add it to QuestionCollection How could I know the most like and most Viewed question.

Comment: Tou say you want to reduce the number of reads. How mant read operations are you performing and how much you want to reduce them?

Comment: see edit @AlexMamo

Comment: I understand. I'll write you an answer right away.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most efficient schema I can think of, is the following:

```
Firestore-root
    |
    --- questions (collections)
    |     |
    |     --- questionId (document)
    |            |
    |            --- questionId: "02cubnmO1wqyz6yKg571"
    |            |
    |            --- title: "Question Title"
    |            |
    |            --- date: August 27, 2018 at 6:16:58 PM UTC+3
    |            |
    |            --- comments (colletion)
    |            |     |
    |            |     --- commentId
    |            |            |
    |            |            ---commentId: "5aoCfqt2w8N8jtQ53R8f"
    |            |            |
    |            |            ---comment: "My Comment"
    |            |            |
    |            |            ---date: August 27, 2018 at 6:18:28 PM UTC+3
    |            |
    |            --- likes (colletion)
    |            |     |
    |            |     --- likeId (document)
    |            |            |
    |            |            --- userId: true
    |            |
    |            --- views (colletion)
    |            |     |
    |            |     --- viewId (document)
    |            |            |
    |            |            --- userId: true
    |            |
    |            --- tags ["tagId", "tagId"]
    |
    --- tags (collections)
          |
          --- tagId (document)
                |
                --- tagId: "yR8iLzdBdylFkSzg1k4K"
                |
                --- tagName: "Tag Name"
```

In which the `comments`, `likes` and `views` are colletions under `questionId` document. Unlike in Firebase real-time database where to display a list of question you would have been downloaded the entire question object, in Cloud Firestore this is not an issue anymore. So to avoid querying using a `where` methods, you can simply get a specific question like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
DocumentReference questionIdRef = rootRef.collection("questions").document(questionId);
questionIdRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(/* ... */);
```

Because you can have hundreds, thousands or even more comments, likes and views to a single question, storing the data into an array will not help you. According to the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model):

> Cloud Firestore is optimized for storing large collections of small documents.

For example, to get all the comments of a specific question, you can use the following query:

```
Query query = rootRef.collection("questions/"+questionId+"comments").orderBy("date", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);
```

Because a question can have only a few tags, you can simply use an array. To get all questions with a specific tag, you can use the following query:

```
Query query = rootRef.collection("questions/"+questionId+"tags").whereArrayContains("tags", tagId);
```

One more thing to remember, even if `tags` object is stored in the database as an array, `document.get("tags")` will return an **`ArrayList`** and not an `array`.

If you also want to count the number of likes or any other number of documents within a collection, please see my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48534676/get-collectionreference-count/48540276)**.

**Edit:**

According to your comments:

> If I want to show the most liked question of all to a user. How could I do this?

You should add the number of likes as a property inside the question object and then you can query the database according to it like this:

```
Query query = rootRef.collection("questions").orderBy("numberOfLikes", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);
```

According to **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48534676/get-collectionreference-count/48540276)** you can also store the number of likes in the Firebase real-time database and you can increase/decrease it using **[Firebase Transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48307610/how-to-save-users-score-in-firebase-and-retrieve-it-in-real-time-in-android-stud)**.

> secondly if I want to show all the question related to a tag like mathematics (show all question which have mathematics tag) ??

As also mentioned above you can take atvantage of the `whereArrayContains` method. You can also store the tags as String and not as id. For that, you need to change this structure:

```
--- tags ["tagId", "tagId"]
```

to

```
--- tags ["mathematics", "chemistry"]
```

And the code should look like this:

```
Query query = rootRef.collection("questions/"+questionId+"tags").whereArrayContains("tags", "mathematics");
```

> the statement (userId: true) saves a lot of data repetition

Yes it does.

Comment: If I want to show the most liked question of all to a user. How could I do this. and secondly if I want to show all the question related to a tag like mathematics (show all question which have mathematics tag) ??

Comment: and @AlexMamo  the statement (userId: true) saves a lot of data repetition

Comment: @XarEAhmer Please see my updated answer, where I have also answered in the edit section, your new questions.

Comment: I appreciate your help ..Also have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52021119/save-documentsnapshot-for-pagination-in-firestore-android

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look and if I'll know the answer, I'll write it to you.

Comment: rootRef.collection("questions/"+questionId+"tags") . Your last query for tag only works for single question. I want to show all the question which have mathematics tag .

Comment: The last query containts also the `.whereArrayContains("tags", "mathematics");` which searches for every questions in all `questions` collection that has set `mathematics` as a tag.

Comment: If I create an array of tagName, Can we search for all the question with this tag. I mean can we search collection on basis of array item.

Comment: Yes you can. This is what I have explained in my answer and also in my last comment. Please see official documentation regarding [array membership](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership).

Comment: plz have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52096781/fetch-collection-on-basis-of-array-item

Comment: Ok, I will and if I'll know the answer, I'll write it to you.

Comment: so if I read one Question then inner comments documents will be counted or just 1 read will consider?

Comment: @akshaybhange Since the comments exist in a different collection, it will be counted separately.

Comment: It seems like off topic question, but how many requests in this code samples? I mean is it one read request (as Firebase metrics count it): `rootRef.collection("questions/"+questionId+"comments").orderBy("date", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)`