# How can I take data from two different db.collections and unite them under one class in Kotlin-Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I want to take datas from 2 different data collections and unite them under one class. My first collection's name is "Posts" and the other one is "UserDetails". I want to take "downloadUrl" and "comment" from Posts and "username" from UserDetails. But I can't do this. Here is my code:

```
class FeedsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding : ActivityFeedsBinding
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var db : FirebaseFirestore
    private lateinit var postArrayList : ArrayList<Post>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityFeedsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)
        binding.recyclerView

        auth = Firebase.auth
        db = Firebase.firestore

        postArrayList = ArrayList<Post>()
        getData()


    }

    private fun getData(){
        db.collection("Posts").addSnapshotListener { value, error ->
            if(error != null){
                Toast.makeText(this,error.localizedMessage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }else{
                if(value != null){
                    if(!value.isEmpty){ //is not empty
                        val documents = value.documents
                        for(document in documents){
                            //casting
                            val comment = document.get("comment") as String
                            val downloadUrl = document.get("downloadUrl") as String
                            val post = Post(comment,downloadUrl)
                            postArrayList.add(post)



                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        db.collection("UserDetails").addSnapshotListener { value, error ->
            if(error != null){
                Toast.makeText(this,error.localizedMessage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }else{
                if(value != null){
                    if(!value.isEmpty){ //is not empty
                        val documents = value.documents
                        for(document in documents){
                            //casting
                            val username = document.get("username") as String
                            val post = Post(username,comment,downloadUrl)
                            postArrayList.add(post)



                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }


        }
```

How can I make this happen?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69805908/firebase-query-to-fetch-data-from-two-nodes-together/69809023#69809023) out. It will help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the root cause of the confusion is that there’s no apparent way that a post from the `Posts` collection is related to a user from the `UserDetails` collection. In order to solve this problem, you would need to refactor your database. My suggestion is to add a `userID` field to each Post document, `userID` being related to a user from the `UserDetails` collection. In the `UserDetails` collection, the same userID should uniquely identify a user. You should review this [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52044566/) about how to design a Firestore database structure.

With these changes in mind, I rewrote your function to query the `UserDetails` collection with the userID that is present in the `Post` document. The matching username from the document in the query is used to create Post objects that go into the `ArrayList`.

```
 private fun getData(){
    db.collection("Posts").addSnapshotListener { value, error ->
        if(error != null){
            Toast.makeText(this,error.localizedMessage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
        else{
            if(value != null){
                if(!value.isEmpty){ //is not empty
                    val documents = value.documents
                    for(document in documents){
                        //casting
                        val comment = document.get("comment") as String
                        val downloadUrl = document.get("downloadUrl") as String
                        //Getting the user ID from a post document
                        val userID = document.get("userID") as String
                        val userName: String
                        
                        //Querying the userDetails database searching for the matching userID
                        db.collection("userDetails").whereEqualTo("userID", userID).get()
                            .addOnSuccessListener { userDocs ->
                                for (doc in userDocs) {
                                    userName = doc.get("username") as String // Getting the username from the document
                                }
                            }
                        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                            Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", exception)
                            }
                        val post = Post(comment,downloadUrl, userName)
                        postArrayList.add(post)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There is more information about how to build queries to Firestore in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection).