# Iterating Firestore Android collection on basis of ID or attribute

Tags: java, android, firebase, pagination, google-cloud-firestore

> I want to iterate a collection which starts at collection document ID.

Is there any method like below which let us read data start at an id or an attribute id?

```
 db.collection("questions").startReadingDocumentAt("02cubnmO1wqyz6yKg571 ").limit(10).get()
```

or

```
db.collection("questions").startReadingWhereEqualTo("questionID","02cubnmO1wqyz6yKg571 ").limit(10).get()
```

**I know I can read that DocumentSnapShot on basis of Id** and can then start iterating with lastVisible item. but it cost me two read operation. Can it be done in one.

```
Firestore-root
    |
    --- questions (collections)
    |     |
    |     --- 02cubnmO1wqyz6yKg571 (questionId document) // myID and my questionID is same
    |            |
    |            --- questionId: "02cubnmO1wqyz6yKg571"
    |            |
    |            --- title: "Question Title"
    |            |
    |            --- date: August 27, 2018 at 6:16:58 PM UTC+3
    |            |
```

I already have gone [**through this**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors)

**Explanation**

I don't want to do `RecyclerView pagination`. I want to **load next 10 question** each time an Activity starts. So I call the query in the same manner but it requires me to save the **DocumentSnapShot**. So I decided to save the questionID and read data on basis of it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no:

```
startReadingDocumentAt("02cubnmO1wqyz6yKg571")
```

nor

```
startReadingWhereEqualTo("questionID","02cubnmO1wqyz6yKg571")
```

In firestore but according to your database schema, to solve this, you can use the following query:

```
db.collection("questions").
    whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("questionID","02cubnmO1wqyz6yKg571")
    .limit(10)
    .get()
    addOnCompleteListener.(/* ... */)
```

More informations [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query#whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)):

> Creates and returns a new Query with the additional filter that documents must contain the specified field and the value should be greater than or equal to the specified value.

Comment: yes I appreciate but one issue is remaining in https://stackoverflow.com/a/52040609/3496570

Comment: @XarEAhmer Which is? I already commented on your last comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [query cursors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors).  E.g.:

```
db.collection("questions")
    .orderBy("questionID")
    .startAt("02cubnmO1wqyz6yKg571")
    .limit(10)
    .get()
```