# How to get document id of the postion of recycler view Item?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I was using `firebaseUI` library to populate recycler view using `firestore` database.
when I try to retrieve the **document id** when i click on recycler view item it was like this

```
 DocumentSnapshot snapshot = getSnapshots()
              .getSnapshot(holder.getAdapterPosition());
          final String countryName = snapshot.getId();
```

I tred this code but `getSnapshots()` appears by the red colored word and nt workng inside `onbindeviewolder` so  I tried this but not working too

```
DocumentReference aa=firebaseFirestore.collection("MainCategories").document(String.valueOf(SS));
            String aaa=aa.getId();
```

So is there any method to retrieve the document id because the code above **is not working here**

```
 private class CategoriesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AllCategoriesViewHolder> {
         private List<mainCategroies> categorylist;

         CategoriesAdapter(List<mainCategroies> categorylist) {
              this.categorylist = categorylist;

         }

         @NonNull
         @Override
         public AllCategoriesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
              View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_maincategory, parent, false);
              return new AllCategoriesViewHolder(view);
         }

         @Override
         public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final AllCategoriesViewHolder holder, int position) {
              final String categoryName = categorylist.get(position).getCategory_Name();
              holder.setCategory_Name(categoryName);
              String d = categorylist.get(position).getImageUrl();
              holder.setImageUrl(d);

              MainActivityProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              holder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {



              }
              });

         }

         @Override
         public int getItemCount() {
              return categorylist.size();
         }
         }
```

the holder class

private class AllCategoriesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
     private View view;

```
 public AllCategoriesViewHolder(final View itemView) {
      super(itemView);
      view = itemView;

 }

 void setCategory_Name(String category_Name) {
      TextView names = view.findViewById(R.id.CategoryName);
      names.setText(category_Name);

 }


 void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
      ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.MainCat_CardViewImage);
      Picasso.get()
     .load(imageUrl)
     .fit()
     .into(imageView);
 }
 }
```

and the model class

```
public class CountryItem {
     private String CountryName;
public CountryItem(){

}
     public CountryItem(String countryName) {
     CountryName = countryName;
     }

     public String getCountryName() {
     return CountryName;
     }

     public void setCountryName(String countryName) {
     CountryName = countryName;
     }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: when I try to add        DocumentSnapshot snapshot = getSnapshots() <<getSnapshots appears by red color

Comment: In which method you are writing this ?

Comment: in holder.itemview.setonclick.see my update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method you are trying to get uid of item i.e:

```
DocumentSnapshot snapshot = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(holder.getAdapterPosition());
final String countryName = snapshot.getId();
```

will work only in case of `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter`. As you are using a `RecyclerView.Adapter` you have to add uid in your Model class and then Retrieve it.

**CountryItem.class**

```
public class CountryItem {
    private String CountryName;
    private String uid;
   //add getters and setters
}
```

And while Retrieving the data from firestore add uid field to your object. I assume you are using query for this then it would be like:-

```
Query query = firestore.collection("Collection").orderBy("CountryName",Query.Direction.ASCENDING);

query.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
        for(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot: documentSnapshots) {
            CountryItem countryItem = documentSnapshot.toObject(CountryItem.class);

             countryItem.setuid(documentSnapshot.getId().toString());
             countryItemList.add(countryItem);
        }
    }

});
```

And `onClick` of an item you can get uid and pass to your method:-

```
holder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String uid = categorylist.get(position).getUid();

     }
});
```

Comment: I will try it when I open my project, so does it work when I use a name for the document like america, england etc...?

Comment: Yes, it will work if your uid name is like country name. You just have do little changes in the code.

Comment: it works but it is not the direct way to get the id but any way  thanks for your help