# Firebase recyclerview adapter pagination

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, pagination

I'm using RecyclerView with FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.But when i run my app. RecyclerView load all data. But I want to load first 10 item then user reached bottom load another 10.

I searched pagination but all tutorials are automatically assuming that i keep my data in reference that i gave adapter.But İ keep data like this.

[Actual Post data tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBSOv.jpg)

All post data is stored under "postall" parent.

[User Main feed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlhd1.jpg)

And user run app recycler view get second picture get post key from there and create new reference then load data.

My code:

```
options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Post>().setQuery(reference,Post.class).build();
    vhadapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, viewholder>(options) {
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }
        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final viewholder holder, final int position, @NonNull Post model) {

            getRef(position).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    DatabaseReference reference1=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("postall").child(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                    reference1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                                //get data
                            }
                            else{

                            }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public viewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.home_item_image,viewGroup,false);

            return new viewholder(view);
        }
    };
    vhadapter.setHasStableIds(true);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(vhadapter);


    vhadapter.startListening();
```

how can i make pagination in this case.

[place where recyclerview get data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDwVW.jpg)

Reycler view read all of this data getpost key from data,create new databse reference to actual data then load data.But i want to do load 10 item at beggining then when user reached recyclerview bottom load another 10.

Comment: If you want at some point to try [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50741958/how-to-paginate-firestore-with-android)** is a recommended way in which you can paginate queries by combining query cursors with the limit() method. I also recommend you take a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KdgKvLll07s)** for a better understanding.

Comment: @AlexMamo I'm not using firestore im using realtime databse.I've edited my question take a look.