# Firestore retrive documents with limit in recycleview

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get documents from the firestore in order of date and use their data into recycleview but to have limit to 10 documents so when I get to the 10th view on the recycle I will load another 10 documents from firestore which their data will appear in the recycle, instead of getting all documents at one time, is there a way to do so or a method built in firestore?

Comment: Hi @Shimshon Polak, welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to add the necessary punctuation and capitalization to your question. A question that is easy to read will more likely get a good answer. You might want to take a look at the guidelines : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can also check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50741958/how-to-paginate-firestore-with-android)** out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're talking about [paging query results](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors), which Firestore does support.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for but had hard time to find it.