# load previous comments in firebase firestore not work as expected in anrdoid

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing an android app with post and comments using the firebase firestore database. In the comment section, I am loading the lastest 20 comments using the following code

```
        val db= FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

        db.collection("comments")
            .whereEqualTo("post_id", postId)
            .limit(20)
            .orderBy("time", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            .get(Source.SERVER)
            .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->


            }
            .addOnFailureListener { exception ->

            }
```

I show these comments in recyclerview. When the user clicks previous comments I fetch timestamp of older comment and  run following code

```
        val db= FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

        db.collection("comments")
            .limit(20)
            .whereLessThan("time",timestamp)
            .whereEqualTo("post_id", postId)
            .orderBy("time", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            .get(Source.SERVER)
            .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->


            }
            .addOnFailureListener { exception ->

            }
```

it fetches 20 documents from firestore database. But it doesn't fetch older comment. Instead, it fetches the latest comments.

when I remove .orderBy("time", Query.Direction.DESCENDING) it loads very first comments from document for that post id

For example.If the post contains 60 comments. first, I want to load 60-40 comments. then I want to load 40-20. then 20-0 .

Comment: For pagination you'll typically want to use the `startAt()`/`startAfter()` methods of the Firestore API, to which you can pass the anchor document.

Comment: can i pass document id instead of document?

Comment: Just the ID isn't enough. You need either a document instance or the fields that you order/filter on, plus the ID. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query.html#startAt(java.lang.Object...)

Comment: @Akashkv **[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50741958/how-to-paginate-firestore-with-android)** is a recommended way in which you can paginate queries by combining query cursors with the limit() method. I also recommend you take a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KdgKvLll07s)** for a better understanding.

Comment: Actually, I could make it work with pagination provided by firestore library. Thank you all