# Android - Firestore returns an empty query using startAfter() and limit()

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to implement a pagination system using Firebase Firestore **startAfter()** and **limit()** query methods. The first query is returned successfully, but the second one returns an empty snapshot.

- Here's my **getNextPage()** method :

  ```
  fun getNextPage(paginationSize : Long) : TrendingRepository {
  database.collection("app")
      .document("data")
      .collection("offers")
      .orderBy("discount")
      .startAfter(lastVisible)
      .limit(paginationSize)
      .get().addOnSuccessListener { snapshot ->

          Log.i("TrendingRepo", "pagination size : $paginationSize")
          val newList = ArrayList<Offer>()

          if (!snapshot.isEmpty) {
              lastVisible = snapshot.documents[snapshot.size() - 1]
          }

          for (document in snapshot) {
              val item = document.toObject(Offer::class.java)
              newList.add(item)
              Log.i("TrendingRepo", "at position: ${newList.indexOf(item)} got item: ${item.id}")
          }

          successListener?.onSuccess(newList)

      }.addOnFailureListener {
          failureListener?.onFailure(it.localizedMessage)
      }

  return this
  }
  ```
- here's my Logcat :

> TrendingRepo: pagination size : 48 // first try
>
> TrendingRepo: at position: 0 got item: 0pqcRzSd06WWlNNmcolu
>
> TrendingRepo: at position: 1 got item: 7I7wiSYt5yEBWwN08bqJ
>
> ...
>
> TrendingRepo: at position: 45 got item: 4B3dEPhFLqhKrYpLWYE7
>
> TrendingRepo: at position: 46 got item: 4ddLqiGe8ReXW8SKq2Q6
>
> TrendingRepo: at position: 47 got item: 4uVnnGNAmKvGUUHcV01n
>
> TrendingRepo: pagination size : 48 // second try
>
> //no more logging, data is empty

Comment: Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50741958/how-to-paginate-firestore-with-android)** out. Is Java code but hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a case in which the items are less than the pagination size So here is the code

```
private var lastVisible: DocumentSnapshot? = null
private var isLastPage: Boolean = false
private var isDocEmpty: Boolean = false

var ref: Task<QuerySnapshot>? = null

 if (lastVisible != null) {
ref = database.collection("app").document("data").collection("offers").orderBy("discount").startAfter(lastVisible).limit(paginationSize).get()
 } else {
ref = database.collection("app").document("data").collection("offers").orderBy("discount").limit(paginationSize).get()
 }


 ref.addOnSuccessListener { documents ->

            hideProgress()
            isDocEmpty = documents.isEmpty



            if (!isDocEmpty) {
                lastVisible = documents.last()
                isLastPage = documents.size() < paginationSize
            }

            isLoading = false
        }
            .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                Log.w("TAG", "Error getting documents: ", exception)
                isLoading = false
                hideProgress()
            }
```

I hope this will helps you.

Comment: The items are successfully loaded, I used => if (lastVisible != null) {
            newQuery = newQuery.startAfter(lastVisible!!)
        }
and then set the limit and get the page.
I was about to break my MVP architecture and switch to FirestorePagingAdapter, Thank you!
I'm already using isLoading and allData booleans in my custom adapter.