# How to Paginate the Query in Firestore Android Application?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

I am using the below code, which working successfully using the filters. Now I just need to paginate my query before passing it to the adapter. I want to implement FirestorePagingAdapter, but not able to do so as the **FirestorePagingOptions** object had to be passed to the adapter, but the adapter type is not accepting it, as it is only accepting the **Query** object and have no idea if I can convert one type to another. Please help me out to paginate, either by using **FirestorePagingOptions** or some other way

I have commented the line where the pagination should be done.

I am using Firestore Database for the Android Project in RecyclerView With Filters option

```
public void onFilter(Filters filters) {
        // Construct query basic query
        Query query = mFirestore.collection("posts").orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

        // Category (equality filter)
        if (filters.hasCategory()) {
            query = query.whereEqualTo("postcategory", filters.getCategory());
        }


        // Limit items
      //  query = query.limit(7);

        // Update the query
        PostsRef = query;

        //Pagination


        adapter.setQuery(query);

        // Set header
        mCurrentSearchView.setText(Html.fromHtml(filters.getSearchDescription(getActivity().getApplicationContext())));

        // Save filters
        mViewModel.setFilters(filters);
    }
```

Comment: that guy is explaining pagination nicely https://youtu.be/HQgJvHXsNOQ

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan I have checked this video already, it is using document snapshot to retrieve the data, but I can't do so, as I have to pass the query to the adapter as you can see in the above code to retrieve the data, I am trying to figure out to paginate the query to Pass it to the Adapter something similar to FirestorePagingOptions

Comment: i think to use firebasePaginOptions you have to use firestoreRecyclerAdapter please refer https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/firestore/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/firestore

Comment: **[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50741958/how-to-paginate-firestore-with-android)** is a recommended way in which you can paginate queries by combining query cursors with the limit() method. I also recommend you take a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KdgKvLll07s)** for a better understanding.

Comment: @AlexMamo I have already gone through this recommendation of yours, but where the actual thing begins in your recommendation is here at "query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>()", but as you can in my above question I need to pass the query to the adapter which will retrieve the data, How I am supposed to do that? I can't change the adapter configuration as it working fine for the filtering feature in the application. One working thing can't be applied to everything, I hope you understand, my requirement is different as per your recommendation. Please Advise

Comment: @AlexMamo Hey, can you help me how to implement the your suggestion in context to my adapter?