# Setting Query for Pagination in Android Application Using Firestore Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

Below is the code I am using to filter the data. The Query passed to the method contains a **whereEqualTo()** clause to filter the data accordingly. To display the list I have to set the query to the adapter like this

> adapter.setQuery(query1);

and then set the adapter to the recyclerView as this

> recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

Till this code loads the documents accurately according to the limit. But now when the pagination has to be performed I again set the adapter with another query **nextQuery** which loads the new data but replaces the previously loaded data, but I want to add the new data to previously loaded data and not to replace the previously loaded data

How should I correct this? I want to achieve the pagination here. I am using Firestore as backend for my android application.

If any more information is required please let me know

The index for the firestore database had also been created.

CODE

```
public void Paginate1(Query query, Filters filters){

        Log.d("queryCheck", filters.toString() + "Hello 1");
        Query query1 = query.limit(5);



        query1.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                    adapter.setQuery(query1);

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    lastVisible = task.getResult().getDocuments().get(task.getResult().size() - 1);

                    RecyclerView.OnScrollListener onScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                            if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
                                isScrolling = true;
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                            LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager());
                            int firstVisibleItemPosition = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                            int visibleItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                            int totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();

                            if (isScrolling && (firstVisibleItemPosition + visibleItemCount == totalItemCount) && !isLastItemReached) {
                                isScrolling = false;
                                Query nextQuery = query1.startAfter(lastVisible).limit(2);
                                nextQuery.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> t) {
                                        if (t.isSuccessful()) {
                                            adapter.setQuery(nextQuery);
                                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                            lastVisible = t.getResult().getDocuments().get(t.getResult().size() - 1);

                                            if (t.getResult().size() < 2) {
                                                isLastItemReached = true;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }

                    };

                    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(onScrollListener);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                }
            }
        });
    }
```

SETQUERY in Adapter

```
public void setQuery(Query query) {
        // Stop listening
        stopListening();

        // Clear existing data
        mSnapshots.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();

        // Listen to new query
        mQuery = query;
        startListening();
    }
```

Comment: **[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50741958/how-to-paginate-firestore-with-android)** is a recommended way in which you can paginate queries by combining query cursors with the limit() method. I also recommend you take a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KdgKvLll07s)** for a better understanding.

Comment: @AlexMamo if you can see, I have implemented the same thing, but not successful. Please understand my question and help me.

Comment: @AlexMamo I know you are an expert in firebase and I am new to this, and learning many things, please help me with this project, I am stuck on this for past few weeks.