# How to convert a Map into arrayList from firestore document

Tags: java, android, arraylist, google-cloud-firestore

My goal is to get query a collection and get the documents each document has three or five hashmap in it .my aim is to get the documents with different id's and populate in nested recycler view . But i facing trouble in converting the map values into arraylist

My Main Model class:

public class BattleGroupPosts {

```
private String userId;
public ArrayList<PostBattle> userPost;

public BattleGroupPosts() {
} ///below there getters and setters and constructions are there
```

My PostBattle Modelclass:

```
public class PostBattle {

private String id;
private String imageuri;
private String description;
private String publisher;
private String tags;
private String challenge_tittle;
private int NumberOfLikesPoints;
private int battle_post_count;
private long TimeLimit;
private Boolean post_time_done;
private @ServerTimestamp
Date timestamp;

public PostBattle() {
} //below the getter and setter and constructor
```

Querying from firestore:

```
private List<BattleGroupPosts> battleGroupPosts;
private ArrayList<PostBattle> battlePostLists;

    private void GettingAllBattleGroupPosts(){
    battleGroupPosts = new ArrayList<>();
    battlePostLists = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new BattlGroupAdapter(mContext,battleGroupPosts);//Setting the adapter
    battle_posts.setAdapter(adapter);


    CollectionReference GroupIdRef = mFirestore
            .collection("OpenBattle")
            .document(BattlesPost_creator)
            .collection("BattlePost")
            .document(BattlePost_id)
            .collection("Participants");
    GroupIdRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());

                    final BattleGroupPosts groupPosts = document.toObject(BattleGroupPosts.class);
                    groupPosts.setUserId(groupPosts.getUserId());


                    groupPosts.setUserPosts(battlePostLists);

                    Map<String, PostBattle> batPost = (Map<String, PostBattle>) document.get("userPost1");
```

I get stuck here  i don't know how to to add these to array list in the model class i tried converting hashMap to arraylist but my images getting populated with all items Id's in recylerview as it is in the for loop i guess.
my method try:

```
List<PostBattle> newList = new ArrayList<PostBattle>(batPost.values());

                    Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: liisd:" + newList.get(0));
                    PostBattle postBattle = new PostBattle();
                    postBattle.setImageuri(String.valueOf(newList.get(1)));
                    postBattle.setNumberOfLikesPoints(Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(newList.get(2))));

                    battlePostLists.add(postBattle);

                    battleGroupPosts.add(groupPosts);

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); ///These methods i did it inside for the loop
```

Have tried this :

```
                    PostBattle postBattle = new PostBattle();

                    Object value = batPost.get("imageuri");

                    postBattle.setImageuri(String.valueOf(value));
                     Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: value: " + value);
                     battlePostLists.add(postBattle);

                    groupPosts.setUserPosts(battlePostLists);

                    battleGroupPosts.add(groupPosts);

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

And this too:

```
    Map<String, Object> idMaps = document.getData();
                    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> id : idMaps.entrySet()){
                        String userId = id.getKey();

                        Object yourObject = id.getValue();

                        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: IDSSS: " + userId);
                        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: Object: " + yourObject);
                        

                        Map<String, PostBattle> batPost = (Map<String, PostBattle>) document.get("userPost1");

                        PostBattle postBattle = new PostBattle();
                        Object value = batPost.get("imageuri");
                        postBattle.setImageuri(String.valueOf(value));
                        batPost.clear();

                        battlePostLists.add(postBattle);
```

[image: my database]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to parse the map to get values, you can do this for multiple keys:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, PostBattle> params : batPost.entrySet()) {
     if (params.getKey().equals("imageuri")) { // or something else
//add to your arraylist  

                                    }
}
```

or if you require only one:

```
String imageuri = batPost.getKey("imageuri").toString();
```

add the above image uri to your arraylist

If you want to seperate on basis of ids:

```
Map<String, yourobject> idmaps = document.getData();
for (Map.Entry<String, yourobject> id : idmaps.entrySet()) {
// do your code here
// first get the id 
String userid = id.getKey();

//then do what you have done above
yourobject = id.getValue();

// do your logic on above object this will seperate your userids

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time ! but i couldn't use the get key to string line  String imageuri = batPost.getKey("imageuri").toString();

Comment: This will basically return PostBattle object which I am converting to string

Comment: cloud firestore output is just like map inside map and simultaneously, you specified document.get("userPost1") well thats the last map in the list

Comment: instead of String i used Object now i can get the image uri ...But for some reason the array list is adding the second id image url also into the list ...can you help me with this Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by second id image uri

Comment: sorry for not being clear .. if you see my image i am getting the both image uri in the same id .. instead of getting in different ids

Comment: oh i see thats because your document final deadpoint is participants and not the document

Comment: to do that you can do the same as above on document.getData(), create a map on it and get keys which are ids and values inside it

Comment: ok! can you please just provide some tips on it how to do it.

Comment: I couldn't solve with this ..even with that image are showing multiple time i. getting looped several times ... i dont know why... but anyways thanks for your time and effort .