# How to add load more functionality in android recyclerview using Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, android-paging

I am working on a Android project where I am showing 1000+ text formatted data in the recyclerview and I am taking data from Firebase Realtime database, now problem is when user open app and scroll they face lagging issue so that is why I decided to add pagination in the Recyclerview using this I and load only few amounts of data and when user scroll the recyclerview and go to the end point they got another few data, In this way I can handle the recyclerview lagging issue. I search for it in the google and go through the different tutorials but I am not getting the actual code & I am also a beginner so that is why I am not understand how to implement it, so anyone please help me to figure out....I am pasting my code here

**Main Recyclerview Fragment Class**

```
private List<QuotesItem> quoteList;
private DatabaseReference dbquote;
private QuotesAdapter adapter;
private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;

final int ITEM_LOAD_COUNT = 10;
int total_item = 0, last_visible_item;
boolean isLoading = false, isMixData = false;
String last_node = "", last_key = "";

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        binding.homeProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        getDataFromFirebase();

        binding.homeShayari.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        binding.homeShayari.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        adapter = new QuotesAdapter(getContext());
        binding.homeShayari.setAdapter(adapter);

        getUsers();

        binding.homeShayari.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                total_item = layoutManager.getItemCount();
                last_visible_item = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

                if (!isLoading && total_item <= ((last_visible_item + ITEM_LOAD_COUNT))) {
                    getUsers();
                    isLoading = true;
                }
            }
        });

        binding.homeShayariRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        binding.homeShayariRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                        RearrangeItems();
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
}

private void getUsers() {

        if (!isMixData) {

            Query query;

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(last_node)) {
                query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                        .child("quotes")
                        .orderByKey()
                        .limitToFirst(ITEM_LOAD_COUNT);
            } else {
                query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                        .child("quotes")
                        .orderByKey()
                        .startAt(last_node)
                        .limitToFirst(ITEM_LOAD_COUNT);
            }

            query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasChildren()) {
                        List<QuotesItem> quotes = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (DataSnapshot data : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                            for (DataSnapshot snap : data.getChildren()) {
                                quotes.add(snap.getValue(QuotesItem.class));
                            }
                        }

                        last_node = quotes.get(quotes.size() - 1).getId();

                        if (!last_node.equals(last_key)) {
                            quotes.remove(quotes.size() - 1);
                        } else {
                            last_node = "end";
                        }

                        adapter.addAll(quotes);
                        isLoading = false;

                    } else {
                        isLoading = false;
                        isMixData = true;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                    isLoading = false;
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void getDataFromFirebase() {
        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child("quotes")
                .orderByKey()
                .limitToLast(1);
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot quotesKey : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot data : quotesKey.getChildren()) {
                        last_key = data.getKey();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
```

**And here is my firebase realtime database nodes**

[image]

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: If you consider at some point in time to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50741958/how-to-paginate-firestore-with-android)** is a recommended way in which you can paginate queries by combining query cursors with the limit() method. I also recommend you take a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KdgKvLll07s)** for a better understanding.

Comment: thanks for replying but I fix my problem