# Set on Touch Listener not working on Edit Text

Tags: java, android, touch-event

I'm trying to use drawable right on edit text in order to user some information with the help of dialog box. now the that I have been facing is that touch listener works perfect in portrait mode but when I switch to landscape mode and click on edit text the dialog kept on showing no matter if I click on drawable icon or not, I have also made separate layout folder for landscape mode and I have the layout file added in it. The code snippet is attached below that I'm using:

```
et_cnicPassport.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                final int DRAWABLE_LEFT = 0;
                final int DRAWABLE_TOP = 1;
                final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;
                final int DRAWABLE_BOTTOM = 3;

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    if (event.getRawX() >= (et_cnicPassport.getRight() - et_cnicPassport.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width())) {

                        DialogHandler.errorDialog(ForgotPasswordActivity.this, "Forgot Password",
                                "CNIC (xxxxx-xxxxxxx-x)" + "\n" + "Passport No.");
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Don't use `event.getRawX()`. That's the x-coordinate with respect to the whole screen. You want just `event.getX()`, no `Raw`.

Comment: it doesn't work alone i just answered it you can refer to my answer and authenticate it if it;s valid

Comment: Yeah, I guess I didn't really look at the rest of that. Use `getWidth()` instead of `getRight()`, too.

Comment: getRight() and getWidth() both works but u have to subtract righpadding too from it that's mandatory and please remember this is for LANDSCAPE ORIENTATION it works fine on PORTRAIT ORIENTATION no neeed to subtract any padding right()

Comment: Orientation should not affect this calculation at all. You need only determine the minimum of the x-coordinate with respect to the `EditText` itself. To do that for the general case, it would be the width of the `EditText` minus the `Drawable`'s width and the right-hand padding. The `EditText`'s position within its parent is irrelevant, and should not be included anywhere; i.e., using `getRight()` is wrong.

Comment: i have one question here i.e. getwidth() basically gets the width of your view so do we need to use getwidth() because drawable end lies within the view i.e. EditText? and also i have read something in official documentation i.e.  For instance, calling getRight() is similar to the following computation: getLeft() + getWidth()

link: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#getWidth()

Comment: Yeah, basically. You're setting the `OnTouchListener` on the `EditText` itself, so you're only concerned with the coordinates with respect to the `EditText`; i.e., its left-hand side is `0`, no matter where the `EditText` is within its parent, so you only ever need to know its width, and the drawable and padding widths. Also, yes, `getLeft() + getWidth()` will equal `getRight()`, but those `getLeft()` and `getRight()` return the position within the parent, which we're not really concerned with here. Make sense?

Comment: yes i think i got what you meant thank you, i'll use getwidth()

Answer (score 0):

Ifound solution to it, the drawable end had some padding that I wasn't including in the motion action to detect the place for touch so using only event.getX() `is not enough you need to add one more line i.e. yourEditText.getPaddingRight(`) and all you have to do is subtract it with getright and getbound line like this:

```
if (event.getX() >= (yourEditText.getWidth() - yourEditText.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width() - yourEditText.getPaddingRight()))
```