# Android - Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference when doing pagination

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating an app that shows the data in recyclerview.

when I run the app this line of error shows up and I'm having trouble fixing it

```
2022-04-28 21:36:59.212 12509-12509/com.example.chocolate_republic E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.chocolate_republic, PID: 12509
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.chocolate_republic.adapters.UpdateProductAdapter.getItemCount(UpdateProductAdapter.java:70)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:4214)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3680)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
```

**here is my code in the main activity**

```
        firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        
        update_rec = findViewById(R.id.admin_update_rec);
        update_rec.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false));

        Query query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("AllProducts")
                .orderBy("productName",Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
                .limit(10);
        query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    updateProductModelList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult()){
                        UpdateProductModel updateProductModel = documentSnapshot.toObject(UpdateProductModel.class);
                        updateProductModelList.add(updateProductModel);
                    }
                    updateProductAdapter = new UpdateProductAdapter(updateProductModelList);
                    update_rec.setAdapter(updateProductAdapter);
                    lastVisible = task.getResult().getDocuments().get(task.getResult().size()-1);

                    RecyclerView.OnScrollListener onScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                            if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL){
                                isScrolling = true;
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                            int firstVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() ;
                            int visibleItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getChildCount() ;
                            int totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount () ;

                            if (isScrolling && (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount == totalItemCount) && !isLastItemReached){
                                isScrolling = false;

                                Query nextQuery = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                                        .collection("AllProducts")
                                        .orderBy("productName",Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
                                        .startAfter(lastVisible)
                                        .limit(10);
                                nextQuery.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                        for (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult()){
                                            UpdateProductModel updateProductModel = documentSnapshot.toObject(UpdateProductModel.class);
                                            updateProductModelList.add(updateProductModel);
                                        }
                                        updateProductAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                        lastVisible = task.getResult().getDocuments().get(task.getResult().size()-1);
                                        Toast.makeText(AdminUpdateProductActivity.this, "Next Page Loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                        if (task.getResult().size() < 10){
                                            isLastItemReached = true;
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    update_rec.addOnScrollListener(onScrollListener);
                }
            }
        });
```

**the place where the error is showing me**
*return updateProductModelList.size();*

```
public class UpdateProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UpdateProductAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    List<UpdateProductModel> updateProductModelList;

    public UpdateProductAdapter(Context context, List<UpdateProductModel> updateProductModelList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.updateProductModelList = updateProductModelList;
    }

    public UpdateProductAdapter(List<UpdateProductModel> updateProductModelList) {
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.update_product,parent,false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UpdateProductAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Glide.with(context).load(updateProductModelList.get(position).getImg_url()).into(holder.imageView);
        holder.name.setText(updateProductModelList.get(position).getProductName());
        holder.price.setText(String.valueOf(updateProductModelList.get(position).getPrice()));
        holder.stock.setText(String.valueOf(updateProductModelList.get(position).getStock()));
        holder.category.setText(updateProductModelList.get(position).getType());


        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateDetail.class);
                intent.putExtra("update",updateProductModelList.get(position));
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return updateProductModelList.size();

    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView imageView;
        TextView name,price,stock,category;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.update_Item_Name);
            price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.update_Item_price);
            stock = itemView.findViewById(R.id.update_stock);
            category = itemView.findViewById(R.id.update_category);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.update_Item_Img);

        }
    }
}
```

could someone help me fix the error that I am currently getting?

Comment: most simple way `if updateProductModelList == null  0 else updateProductModelList.size()` which takes care of the nullpointer, why it is null is something you'd have to debug

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50741958/how-to-paginate-firestore-with-android) you can find a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have the following constructor:

```
public UpdateProductAdapter(List<UpdateProductModel> updateProductModelList) {
}
```

You are never actually setting the updateProductModelList in the UpdateProductAdapter, so it calls get size on the property which is still null.  Your other constructor appears to do this correctly.