# Pagination with firestore in java Android studio

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I want to add pagination in my project.
I use firestore as database and language is java in android studio. Please help me to how pagination is implement. On internet no one example for java, all examples uses kotlin. Please explain pagination in java.how to implement?????

Comment: Check this https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#java

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50742175/5246885) help?

Comment: This topic is covered in the document and has been covered in many previous [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-firestore%5D%5Bandroid%5D+pagination) already, so I recommend reading those first, trying to make it work from that, and reporting back with a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you get stuck.